# What does Hinduism say about masturbation?

Tags: belief, sex

Semitic religions such as Islam and Christianity consider masturbation to be a sin. What about Hinduism? Please give some authentic quotes for the answers.

Comment: It doesn't say anything about masturbation in Christianity. It talks about lust, which can usually be associated with such, but the act itself is not mentioned. If you feel it does, please direct me to the verse.

Comment: @NuclearPeon - Christianity is not limited to Bible. Matter of fact, what matters far more is what the practitioners of a religion do, not what their book preaches. Majority of Christian dogma has jack shit to do with anything said in the Bible.

Comment: If the practitioners do not practice what Jesus taught, it isn't Christianity although it may be based on its influence. They may not be 100% accurate at deciphering the subtle nuances or they may miss important points and cultural references, but I disagree that Christianity goes beyond the bible; Not only does it include very old texts such as the Torah, but it's a collection of the most accurate and verifiable texts afterwards, esp. of the apostles. The dogma is inaccurate if the authority is anything but from God. I don't mean to hijack this question, but @KiranRS I am skeptical it's a sin

Comment: this is a natural activity. dogmatic misinterpretation of ancient scriptures that does not directly mention this nonsense.

Comment: In college days people used to call this "Hath Yoga". Only in this website, I learned that, that meaning was not true!

Comment: A must read is the parable of the Sower in the Bible. The Answer is there.

Comment: @FrankHestermann the bible is not a valid scripture on this site.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

A glass can be looked on as half empty or half full. I think it is best to rephrase this  question by asking instead - What does Hinduism say about continence (self constraint in sexual matters)?

Swami Nikhilananda in [his writings on Hindu ethics](https://archive.org/details/moralprincipleso0000ansh/page/615/mode/2up) says:

> Besides the objective duties based on the castes and stages of life, there are laid down the common duties of men, the sadharanadharma, which are the foundation of the moral life. Manu, the lawgiver, enumerates these common duties as follows: steadfastness (dhairya), forgiveness (kshama), **good conduct (dama)**, avoidance of theft (chauryabhava), **control of the senses (indriyanigraha)**, wisdom (dhi), learning (vidya), truthfulness (satya) and absense of anger (akrodha)...the aim of Hindu ethics is to enable a man ultimately to conquer his lower self and attain freedom from passion, desire, and attachment.
>
> All Hindu philosophers regardless of their conceptions of the supreme end of man, admit the empirical reality of the individual, endowed with volition, desire, will, conscience or consciousness of duty, emotion, etc. The goal of Hindu ethics is to train these faculties in such a way that they shall lead the individual to the realization of Moksha, or Liberation. Therefore all the schools of philosophy have described the virtues and their opposites in detail. **It is expected of the moral agent that he should follow the former and shun the latter**. We propose to discuss the virtues and their opposites according to the classification of Nyaya and of Patanjali's system.
>
> Vatsyayana, in his commentary on the Nyaya aphorisms, classifies will as impious (papatmika) and auspicious (subha). The impious will leads to unrighteousness (adharma), and the auspicious will, to righteousness (dharma). Righteousness, it is necessary to add, is conductive to the Highest Good, whereas unrighteousness produces evil. The purpose of ethics is to subdue the impious and to manifest the righteous will."
>
> Unrighteousness may take three forms, namely, physical, verbal, and mental, depending upon the condition of its functioning. Physical unrighteousness manifests itself as cruelty (himsa), theft (steya), and **sexual perversion (pratisiddha maithuna)**; verbal unrighteousness, as falsehood (mithya), rudeness (katukti), insinuation (suchana), and gossip (asambaddha); mental unrighteousness, as ill-will (paradroha), covetousness (paradravyabhipsa), and irreverance (nastikya)."
>
> Patanjali...describes the virtues that must be cultivated...chastity or continence...
>
> The practice of continence, highly extolled by all the philosophers and mystics of India, implies, besides the literal meaning of the vow, **abstention from lewdness in thought**, speech, and **action through any of the sense-organs**. Through the practice of this virtue, one develops the capacity for subtle spiritual perception.

Comment: Good answers respond to what is asked and great answers clarifies thought I think this specific answer is in the second category, but would be a great help to ignorant people like me if you can simplify your style a little bit more, in that if you separate your answers from the quotations fro literature that would make it easier to ready and comprehend for people like me

Answer (score 33):

Hindu Scriptures **describe masturbation as a sin.**

The Parashara Smriti, Chapter 12 , Sloka 63 specifically deals with masturbation and provides an expiation(prayaschitta) for that sin too.

> [image]
>
> 63. If a householder willingly causes the discharge of his virile seed otherwise than in sexual intercourse, he should recite the Gayathri
>       verse one thousand times, and should perform three Pranayamas.

Now,for a student (Brahmachari) masturbation is a more serious sin because it then involves breaking of the vow (of celibacy).

> Manu Smriti 2.180. Let him always sleep alone, **let him never waste
>   his manhood; for he who voluntarily wastes his manhood, breaks his
>   vow.**

**So , masturbation is indeed a sin as per Hindu Sastras and the expiation is reciting the Gayatri Mantra 1000 times & doing 3 rounds of pranayama.**

**Edit-**

*For those who don't know what technically constitutes a Pranayama-As per Manu, reciting the Gayatri verse 3 times while holding one's breath inside makes one round of Pranayama*

User Yogi wrote in a [comment](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/697/what-does-hinduism-say-about-masturbation/14932#comment43776_14932)

> Not everyone can recite Gyatri, it needs initiation and only Bramhanas can recite it.

Those who are not initiated into Gayatri can simply do Pranayama without any mantra.A Pranayama, even if it's done without any mantra, is an effective method of destroying sins. But Pranayama done with mantras is even more effective in doing so (Note that these expiation measures are all additional information that are not exactly related to the question).

Comment: So,  combination of "reciting the Gayatri Mantra 1000 times & doing 3 rounds of pranayama." has 1009 times Gayatri mantra (with 9 times during Pranayama)?

Comment: Yes but while chanting 1000 times one can chant loud whereas while chanting alongwith antara kumbhaka the recitation is only in mind because ur nose & lips will be closed.
In general,doing pranayamas like the way mentioned above is an extremely powerful way of removing sins (even great sins) and comes handy when particular expiation rites are too difficult to perform.

Comment: Thanks! BTW, you say Parashara Smriti is particularly Smriti for Kali Yuga. Are there any scriptures which say Parashara Smriti is for Kali Yuga other than Parashara Smriti? I'm not doubting Parashara Smriti but consider all Smriti as one and same. Also, Smriti contradicts with each other.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Its not something that i'm saying.It is so said in PS.And as i have said,i don't know of any scriptures that contradicts with that view point.Possibly there are none.Also ,generally ,all Smritis(Dharma Shastras not puranas) say the same thing,so not much contradictions as such between them.So.other Smritis will also say the same thing about masturbation.Its just the explicit nature of the verse found in PS that makes it important in the context of the question.

Comment: By Smritis i mean here "Dharma Shastras" like Vyasa,Manu,Daksha,Yajnvalkya,Parashara and others.

Comment: I'm not talking about context of Masturbation. As you are writing many answers from PS, i want to know importance of PS as mentioned in other Scriptures.

Comment: @TheDestroyer If u go through a Dharma sAra(the essence of all Dharma Shastras) then u'll find that all major Dharma Shastras are consulted before deciding upon a particular duty/Dharma.Also,pundits who are compiling these "Essences" are well versed in ALL Scriptures.And when they say that PS should have the priority in Kali then we should go by that.We can conclude that no contradictions are present in other Shastras regarding this.All major Dharma Shastras are more or less applicable to Kali but the most precise(or suitable )one is PS.

Comment: Not everyone can recite Gyatri, it needs initiation and only Bramhanas can recite it.

Comment: @Yogi Yes..but that prayaschitta part  is additional.. not relevant to answering the question..For those who are not initiated into gayatri can simply do pranayama without mantra...Pranayama without mantra is called "Agarva" Pranayama(if i can remember correctly as opposed to "Sagarva" which is done with mantra)..Agarva is less effective but still quite effective in removing sins..

Comment: Rickross,Then you should add this specification in the answer

Comment: @Yogi I'll do it a bit later

Comment: Okay but there is no prayaschitta for bramhacharis?!

Comment: @Yogi The prayaschitta is given already ..One who has Brahmopadesam can simply chant the Gayatri 1000 times..Doing Pranayama with or without mantra is also a very effective prayaschitta..plus i think there r more elaborate measures given in Smritis which involves fasting..

Comment: @Rickross It says householder while in case of bramhachari i think its a bigger sin

Comment: @Yogi yes u are right..for Brahmachari the penance is the same penance which is done when a vow is broken..i can't remember the name now..will have to chk ..

Comment: @Yogi Here's a general prayaschitta for anyone..and it can be done by everyone..http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17008/4732

Comment: @Rickross do you know why it is a sin? I am curious towards the background of this smriti verse.

Comment: There is no background as such .. According to Hinduism depositing semen in any other places other than the Yoni (of the wife) is a sin .. so masturbation is a sin .. and so are various other non-vaginal sex.. also we know that it is a sin only because scriptures say so .. otherwise we would hv been just guessing abt the nature of the act .. although our conscience always gives hints @Wikash_hindu

Comment: @rickross I saw you gave some more info here:
https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8744/vedas-and-vedic-dharma-on-homosexuality/15520#15520. Yet I remain curious. I remember from Ayurveda that deposting semen means a loss of energy but I can't remember where I read it.

Comment: @Wikash_hindu Yes that answer also has more related stuffs .. The sexual energy is the basic energy of any being and who wastes way too much by indulging can not make it go up and convert into Ojas.. Retas-> Ojas is the conversion that Hinduism wants to make .. so sexual energy-> spiritual energy

Comment: Actually masturbation is NOT a sin. "Wasting" seed without intercourse is.

Comment: And how is masturbation different from "wasting seed without intercourse"? @Wikash_

Comment: Because masturbation is possible without ejaculation.

Comment: Oh .. so the purpose of masturbation is to un-endingly do it without reaching ejaculation.. amazing. @Wikash_

Comment: Anyways for the kind of masturbation you are mentioning one needs to reframe the Q accordingly. Otherwise everyone will answer considering that there is ejaculation at the end @Wikash_

Comment: "Oh .. so the purpose of masturbation is to un-endingly do it without reaching ejaculation". Where did I say this? You couple masturbation with ejaculation while maturbation does not has to include an ejaculation.

Comment: Your references are only about ejaculation from what I can tell not about masturbation specifically. Masturbation is not a sin: ejaculation not for the purpose of progeny is a sin from your references.

Comment: @Wikash_ Masturbation usually ends with ejaculation .. From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Masturbation) -- Masturbation is the sexual stimulation of one's own genitals for sexual arousal or other sexual pleasure, **usually to the point of orgasm.**

Comment: Sure and usually is not always. Also, not an percentage is given to it in the wiki so usually can mean 51%. Btw there are men who can orgasm without an ejaculation but let's leave that aside. I conclude that nothing is said about masturbation in your references.

Answer (score 6):

Hinduism does not deal with social situations like Western religions do.

There are no chapters on how to deal with women, how to marry, how to divorce, how to have sex, whether to have drugs, whether to have alcohol etc etc. There are no 10 commandments.

There have been various books or literature on topics like society, class, sex etc, but that's on the side. They are again theories written by many people along the way.

Interestingly, if you see India as it is today, there is a lot of ingrained rules on how to live, marry, divorce. A kind of Hindu law. But all of those have come from centuries of learning, shaping, relearning, adapting, adopting, copying, debating, conflicting, dispelling, removing, curtailing, picking, dropping and how you like it.

As a society it slowly adopts what's best in the current context.  Look at child marriage - It was prevalent 2 centuries ago. Now it is unheard of. Sati - prevalent 100 years ago. Now - unheard of. Women at work - unheard of 100 years back. 33% reservation for women in parliament - Now.

So, in a way, the religion has found a non-prescriptive way of dealing with internal change. And the core of it is is a simple idea

**" Nobody is wrong. Nobody is right".**

This concept is the basis of all values that came from India.

==> Debate, conflict, understand, Agree, Accept, Change and keep doing that in circles.

The one thing people outside of India may have noticed is that Indians are always fighting war of words with each other. Now thats the fundamental value that societies need to adapt, and to change.

In a short way, Masturbation was also debated in India by Vatsayana, and he was the first to say OK to it. I dont think, any conflicting ideas have come since then.

Comment: -1 just for your first sentence, 'Hinduism does not deal with social situations'. It is the biggest culture which deals with social situations than any other cultures. As an example, just see about Shodasha Sanskara. Pls consider editing your answer if it make sense.

Comment: There is a difference between a Purana, a Vedas, and other treatise. Description of societies and how the people reacted have come through all the rest of the texts. We will live in confusion as to which ones are religious texts, and which ones are parables, or interpretative or reformative theories which came along the way. But thats fine. I would say that is the essence of Hinduism anyway.

Comment: @Raghuraman.K Agreed! With so much of western way of thinking around I can we still have to free ourself from the English ruling our heads.
Its SAD that KamaSutra is considered as a religions text. Hinduism is ONLY concerned with breaking the Birth-Death cycle and break free from this _Dukkhalay Ashashvatt Sansaar_, AND NOTHING ELSE. Life is NOT a gift rather an opportunity.
But its _Kaliyuga_...and such ignorance is "fine"!

Comment: @Raghuraman.K, you must live in a very different India and follow a very different hinduism than what most hindus know :
how to deal with women - manu smriti, apasthamba sutra .
how to marry - manu smriti, apasthamba sutra .
how to divorce - no chapter on this cos it is not allowed .
how to have sex - no chapter on this cos people already know it .
whom/when to have sex - manu smriti, apasthamba sutra .
whether to have drugs - not allowed .
whether to have alcohol - not allowed .

Answer (score 3):

As the question specifically mentioned the 3 famous religions of today's time, so below answer is based on them. It's important to understand what primary reasons led masturbation being categorised as sinful.

Rather than masturbation, **the act of watching a women with bad intent is considered a grievous sin in hinduism, christianity and islam- which religion the person belongs doesn't matter.**

Christianity:
https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/52/49996
**"The root of the matter is lust.**

Matthew 5:28 But I say to you that everyone who looks at a woman with lustful intent has already committed adultery with her in his heart.

**I would say that the act itself is not the sin, it's the intent of the act."**

Hinduism:

**Lust is described as a root toxin in Hinduism, followed by anger, greed, materialistic attachments {Kaam, krodh, lobh,moha).**

Chapter 3: Karma-yoga
TEXT 37
**Sri-bhagavan uvaca
kama esa krodha esa
rajo-guna-samudbhavah
mahasano maha-papma
viddhy enam iha vairinam**

**God said: It is lust only, Arjuna, which is born of contact with the material modes of passion and later transformed into wrath, and which is the all-devouring, sinful enemy of this world.**

**Thus, it's always best to protect ourselves to prevent the cause of bad happenings by avoiding looking at females with bad intentions.**
Sin committed by thoughts:
It is well-understood that nothing is hidden from God, not even our thoughts, so even if we plan devious activities in our mind, is accountable as a sin.
Holding filthy conversation or hurling dirty comments towards a pregnant woman, or a woman on her periods, is a grave sin. Involving in acts of violence or uncivilized activities against, children, woman and any weak creature, is an unforgivable sin in the eyes of God.

Islam advises-

**It is incumbent on women and girls to observe ḥijāb; it is equally incumbent on men to avoid looking in ḥarām way and keeping away from mixing with the opposite sex, which normally leads to temptation and corruption.As a matter of obligatory caution, one should not view pictures of non-maḥram women on television that are broadcast live. As for that which is not broadcast live, there is no problem in it provided it is done without ill intentions and the fear of falling in ḥarām.**

Accordingly, there is no objection to it, as per Islamic law, if it is not done with lust, evil intention, and does not lead to a bad result. However, since watching obscene pictures is inherently intertwined with looking with sexual urge, and it is a precursor to committing ḥarām acts, it is, therefore, ḥarām.

In brief,
the act of masturbation in itself isn't a sin, even night fall occurs in nature- but the ill ignorant intentions towards female gender accompanied degrades spiritual progress and consciousness by blocking the root chakra, which is the starting point for spiritual progress and experience God realizations.

**Thus, ***the scriptures wants to protect the mentality of humans towards females, who have obtained the gifted body to play the role of nurturing mothers*** on the earth, which is a godly task in itself.**

Note:

Shrimad Bhagawad Geeta Adhyay 14 Shlok 4:

**SarvayoniShu Kaunteya MurrtayaH SaMbhavanti YaaH  |
Taasaam Brahma Mahat YoniH Aham BeejapradaH Pitaa   ||**

**Whatever forms (of beings) are produced in all wombs, O Arjuna, the great Brahma (Prakriti i.e. the matter at large) is their womb (mother), while I am the seed-giving father to all beings.**

**The eightfold nature, O son of Kunti, is the mother that bears all the beings of different births and I am the father that casts the seed.**

As per above sloka, males shouldn't take pride in thinking that they are father, but actually God is the ultimate father, we are just serving as his instruments, so therefore, one shouldn't take joy in wasting preciously rich sexual energy, as it can be a medium to better serve the holy purpose God described in the Bhagwad Gita-

**Chapter 10: The Opulence of the Absolute
TEXT 28
ayudhanam aham vajram
dhenunam asmi kamadhuk
prajanas casmi kandarpah
sarpanam asmi vasukih**

TRANSLATION
**Of weapons, I am the thunderbolt; among cows I am the surabhi, givers of abundant milk. Of procreators I am Kandarpa, the god of love, and of serpents I am Vasuki, the chief.**

Purport for kandarpa:
**Kandarpa is the sex desire for presenting good sons; therefore Kandarpa is the representative of Krsna. Sometimes sex is engaged in only for sense gratification; such sex does not represent Krsna. But sex for the generation of good children is called Kandarpa and represents Krsna.**

So, true contentment lies in keeping away from toxic habits through right knowledge rather than thinking whether one will be considered sinful by doing this or that- God's special form Yamarajji can only decide on that as such as he's rightly incharged of taking dead beings soul to heaven or hell based on the karmic sheet for further treatments.

Comment: When quoting others, you should use [blockquotes](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/editing-help#simple-blockquotes).

Comment: Updated line1,pointed to the question itself instead.

Comment: I do not see any reference in your answer towards masturbation in Hinduism.

Comment: It's because there isn't any religious practice/sloka related to the act as such. So, have explained the possible sins one comes across.

Answer (score 1):

[Brihadâranyaka upanishad](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbe15/sbe15098.htm) talks about prAyaschitta :

> *4. This, verily, indeed, it was that Uddâlaka Âruṅi knew when he said:-- This, verily, indeed, it was that Nâka Maudgalya knew when he
> said:-- This, verily, indeed, it was that Kumârahârita knew when he
> said: 'Many mortal men, Brahmans by descent, go forth from this world,
> impotent and devoid of merit, namely those who practise sexual
> intercourse without knowing this.' [If] **even this much semen is
> spilled, whether of one asleep or of one awake**, then he should touch
> it, or [without touching] repeat:-- 'What semen has of mine to earth
> been spilt now, Whate'er to herb has flowed, whate'er to water-- This
> very semen I reclaim! Again to me let vigor come! Again, my strength;
> again, my glow! Again the altars and the fire Be found in their
> accustomed place!' Having spoken thus, he should take it with
> ring-finger and thumb, and rub it on between his breasts or his
> eye-brows.*