# Vedas and Vedic dharma on homosexuality

Tags: vedas, belief, scripture, culture, gender

[This](http://www.sacred-texts.com/lgbt/index.htm) link describes that the Vedas have no problem with homosexuality:

> In contemporary India LGBT people face discrimination and marginalization. This results from cultural attitudes imposed by the British during their long occupation of India. **There is no condemnation of homosexuality in the ancient Hindu texts**, and no bias against LGBT people is evident up to the 19th century. In a few Hindu lawbooks, same-gender sexuality is described as producing a state of impurity, but it can be expunged by a ritual bath.

Is it true that the Vedas and other Hindu scriptures accept homosexual people? I mean if homosexuality is against the natural order, then how come the Vedas accept it?

Comment: Isn't it possible that, homosexuality might be a punishment in itself while one's time on earth? After all it's not something which someone *like* to do. Rather it's something which someone *tend* to do.

Comment: Yeah it might be a punishment or fruits of bad karma, but the question is about social acceptability in vedas

Comment: If my memory serves me correctly, it is specifically against the laws of Manu.

Comment: Which law since there was no concept of homosexuality at time of manu then how was it specified in manusmriti and in please provide some proof or the mantra of law book directly

Comment: @iammilind for More discussions post your comments here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38640/disscussion-on-vedanta-and-sexuality

Answer (score 22):

**Homosexuality in men is clearly stated as a sin in the Manu Smriti.**

> मैथुनं तु समासेव्य पुंसि योषिति वा द्विजः । 
>   गोयानेऽप्सु दिवा चैव सवासाः स्नानमाचरेत् ॥ १७४ ॥
>
> maithunaṃ tu samāsevya puṃsi yoṣiti vā dvijaḥ | 
>   goyāne'psu divā caiva savāsāḥ snānamācaret || 174 ||
>
> If **a twice-born man commits an unnatural offence with a male**, or has intercourse with a female, in an ox-cart, or in water, or during the day, — he should take a bath along with his clothes. — (174)
>
> ([Manu Smriti, Chapter 11, Verse 174](http://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc202068.html))

One more shloka from Manu Smriti that condemns homosexuality in men is given below:

> ब्राह्मणस्य रुजः कृत्वा घ्रातिरघ्रेयमद्ययोः । 
>   जैह्म्यं च मैथुनं पुंसि जातिभ्रंशकरं स्मृतम् ॥ ६७ ॥
>
> brāhmaṇasya rujaḥ kṛtvā ghrātiraghreyamadyayoḥ | 
>   jaihmyaṃ ca maithunaṃ puṃsi jātibhraṃśakaraṃ smṛtam || 67 ||
>
> Causing pain to a Brāhmaṇa (by a blow), — smelling at things that should not be smelt, or at wine, — cheating — and **sexual intercourse with a man**, — all this is declared to lead to loss of caste (Gatibhramsa). — (67)
>
> ([Manu Smriti, Chapter 11, Verse 67](http://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201944.html))

EDIT:

The Atri Smriti also mentions homosexuality as a sin and prescribes an expiation measure for the same:

> By discharging semen into inhuman females except a cow, into a woman
>   in [her] menses, **into others that have no female organs (i.e., a man or
>   a eunuch),** or into water one should perform the penance of Santapanam.
>
> ([Atri Smriti, Chapter 1, Verse 268](https://play.google.com/books/reader?id=MC-IK69vF84C&printsec=frontcover&output=reader&hl=en&pg=GBS.PA318))

**Updating the answer:**

Adding some further relevant verses from the Dharmasutra of Apastambha (AD) and that of BaudhAyana (BD).

From BD:

> One who does not have sex with his wife during her season, and one who
>   has sex with her outside her season, **as also one who deposits his
>   semen in a place other than the vagina ––they all incur the same
>   guilt.**
>
> **BD 3.7.2**

From AD:

> A man who ejaculates his semen in any place other than the vagina
>   becomes equal to a thief, equal to a murderer of a Brahmin.
>
> **AD 1.19.15**

In these verses the sanskrit original being used is Ayoni for non-vaginal. Also, these verses prohibit a whole lot of sexual activities besides prohibiting (male-male) homosexuality.

Comment: What is "unnatural offence with a man" ? Is it explained somewhere or interpreted by you ?

Comment: These verses refer to unnatural sexual congress between a man and man..See the sanskrit word being used..MAITHUNAM...

Comment: It wiuld be good if you translate the word maithunam in english version. Not everyone knows sanskit. Also, What does it say about women and women then? Is it only offence when a man is doing it ?

Comment: @Utkarsh In those verse only male to male is dealt with but i think there r other verses which talk about lesbian relation..not that sure will have to check..

Comment: What is the reason for the downvote??

Comment: I have mentioned that in my comments already. You have not referenced any source material and moreover, instead of translating the Sanskrit you are writing your own versions. If maithunam meant sex, then write that, "unnatural offence" can be interpreted as anything. What I can deduce that it's a sin for bramin caste only. But you wrote it as for entire Hindus caste. Which is not true. No aspects of female relationship is discussed. Overall,  I didn't find your answer to be neutral and properly researched

Comment: @Utkarsh 1)I am quoting from Manu Smriti itself..then how can u say that i don't have source?..Quoting like this also allowed without having any online sources..this was what i have been told to do ..2)The translations are not mine..i have just copied the entire thing from a book..3)Even if i have not adressed the lesbian thing does not mean that it shd be downvoted..u can consider it a partial answer and partial answers are allowed here..Anyways i'll try to add an online source for ur satisfaction..

Comment: "By discharging semen into inhuman females **except a cow**"? Can you explain that part?

Comment: Maybe persons born homosexual are born that way because the predicament in itself leads one to a faster spiritual maturity. If it's a sin, it's almost like a force to attain the kingdom understanding of no male or female. To be homosexual is very different from being Heterosexual. Because you're in this strange limbo.

Comment: @Ikshvaku I did not receive notification about ur comment. Anyways, it is explained in this answer: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/18115/4732

Comment: @Utkarsh is right at the point that "**unnatural offence**" is an interpretive translation done by translator. In Sanskrit verse, "Maithunam" is joined to both **पुंसि** and **योषिति**, so its right translation is "**Sexual course with Men and Woman**" instead of "1. **Unnatural offence** with man, and 2. **Sexual course** with woman." Translators often just make their own meanings (quite deviating at times).

Comment: 2nd verse maithunaṃ puṃsi --it means sexual congress with a man (pumsa)..there is no ambiguity here.. @AnuragSingh

Comment: @Rickross no, I was pointing to the first verse "Maithunam tu samaasevya punsi yoshiti vaa". I mean in this verse Maithunam is connected to both Punsi (man) and Yoshiti (woman), so there is no need of giving two different meanings of Maithunam ( 1. Offence for man, 2. Coition for woman ) as the translator has done. And yes, you are right that second verse is unambiguous.

Comment: Terms like Vedic Dharma, Vedic ref etc are loosely used by users here.. Any ref from any scriptures like- Smritis, Puranas will also do... Also Smritis come from the Kalpas which are Vedangas. The Smritis elaborate the Vedic religion only, hence Manu Smriti etc are the correct sources to answer this Q from. If we are waiting for answers from Vedas directly, thn it will go unanswered. @AtharvaPandey

Comment: why does this answer not show up in the top of the list of answers, and other low-score answers are showing up ?

Comment: @Rickross very true that if we wait for references from vedas it will go unanswered because vedas does not quote anything on it and i will have to disagree that manusmritis extend vedas there are several contradicting verses in manusmriti which totally go against vedic verses i can agree that it is hindu text but cannot that it is vedic text to be honest vedas alltogether are complete on its own and does not need any extension all others just dilute the purity of vedic religion

Comment: Doesnt the quedtion alreafy state that homosexuality results in a " state of impurity, but it can be expunged by a ritual bath"? How then is it a sin? I also dont see how it is a sin. Correct me if I am wrong but isnt the Manusmirti just a treatise of what people should have followed at that time? Does it even warrant torure in Naraka?

Comment: State of impurity means sin .. if it was not a sin at all why a ritual bath is ordained as a prayaschitta? .. and for householders Gayatri japa is also prescribed as the remedy. Yes, Manu Smritis talks about hells and related stuffs but not in great details like is done in Puranas. @Vick

Comment: How can you/dare you confuse smriti with sruti Vedas?!?! It totally unanswers the question.

Comment: It answers the question .. see this part in the questions body "Is it true that the Vedas **and other Hindu scriptures** accept homosexual people?". Secondly, Vedas need not talk about everything. Like sins and punishments etc are not found in Vedas. Vedas have six limbs called the Vedangas of which one is Kalpa. These Dharmashastras (Smritis) are part of Kalpa. In order to understand the Vedic religion the Smritis are practical the guidelines.@AvyWam

Comment: My God! How do you have so much knowledge!!

Comment: I don't have much knowledge at all @SethuSrivatsaKoduru

Comment: @Rickross Dont take it as offense 
https://www.google.com/search?q=tu+hai+tereko+pata+nahi+meme&sxsrf=ALeKk016tY4v6Fy7gUSJSjwnaDmSyedEYA:1615788777896&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=EzFfwQ7HQGwDWM%252CfG5EhkUxXxcjzM%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kRFo20E32T2NLgIZbmz4_Q60yE2mw&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj0p42h0rHvAhXdzDgGHaaCAcwQ9QF6BAgPEAE&biw=1366&bih=657#imgrc=EzFfwQ7HQGwDWM

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru haha ...........

Answer (score 5):

Amara Das Wilhelm (of GALVA108.org) describes the various kinds of homosexual males and females and also the causes of human sexuality and gender in ancient Hindu/Vedic society in his book "Tritiya-Prakriti: People of the Third Sex: Understanding Homosexuality, Transgender Identity, and Intersex Conditions Through Hinduism." :

**Homosexual men:**

> The Five Types of Kliba [Homosexual men]
>
> In a chapter of the ***Sushruta Samhita*** (3.2) discussing the conception of
>   progeny, five types of kliba are listed and described as follows:
>
> 1) *Asekya*—he is aroused only by swallowing a man’s semen.
>
> 2) *Saugandhika*—he is aroused only by smelling the genitals of others.
>
> 3) *Kumbhika*—he takes the passive role in anal sex.
>
> 4) *Irshyaka*—he is aroused only by the jealous feelings of seeing others in the
>   act of sexual union.
>
> 5) *Shandha*—he has the qualities and behavior of a woman.
>
> The Sushruta Samhita is an ancient Vedic medical text put into writing
>   sometime around 600 B.C. **All five types of kliba are described as inborn,
>   due to an equal “seed” conception caused by various conditions of the
>   parents.** The Sushruta Samhita distinguishes the shandha from the other four
>   in that the latter are said to possess semen and male characteristics whereas
>   the shandha is completely devoid of these. It also mentions that the first four
>   types of kliba achieve erections through drinking the semen of other men
>   (3.2.44-45) and describes a type of female shandha with the qualities of a
>   man (3.2.43).

**Homosexual women:**

> The Ten Types of Nastriya [Homosexual women, which is only the first two, the rest (besides 3) are mainly impotent and not necessarily homosexual]
>
> Women who are impotent with men are mentioned less frequently in Vedic
>   literature. Nevertheless, at least ten different types of nastriya or third-gender
>   women can be found in various Sanskrit texts and are listed below.
>
> 1) *Svairini*—she engages in lovemaking with other women.
>
> 2) *Kamini*—she engages in lovemaking with both men and women. ["Kami" is the masculine i.e bisexual male]
>
> 3) *Stripumsa*—she is masculine in behavior and form. [Not necessarily homosexual]
>
> 4) *Shandhi*—she is averse to men and has no menstruation or breasts.
>
> 5) *Narishandha*—her womanhood is completely destroyed.
>
> 6) *Varta*—her female “seed” is afflicted in utero.
>
> 7) *Sucivaktra* or *Sucimukhi*—she has an extremely small, undeveloped
>   vagina.
>
> 8) *Vandhya*—her menstruation is absent or suppressed.
>
> 9) *Moghapuspa*—her attempts to unite with the man are fruitless.
>
> 10) *Putraghni*—she has repeated miscarriages.
>
> The svairini is described in the Kama Sutra (2.8); the kamini in the
>   Bhagavata Purana (5.24.16); the stripumsa in the Mahabharata and various
>   astrological texts; the shandhi, sucivaktra, vandhya and putraghni in the
>   Sushruta Samhita (6.38); the shandhi, narishandha, varta, sucimukhi and
>   putraghni in the Caraka Samhita (4.2; 4.4; 6.30), and the moghapuspa in
>   various Sanskrit lexicons. The first three types are physically capable of
>   bearing children whereas the remaining seven are infertile.

**The causes of human sexuality and gender:**

> The Ten Causes of Gender
>
> **Both the *Sushruta* and *Caraka Samhitas* provide elaborate descriptions
>   regarding how and why living entities take birth as male, female or third
>   gender.** Such descriptions can be summarized into the ten contributing factors
>   listed below. In many cases, several or even most of these factors will be
>   involved to some degree.
>
> 1) *Samskara*—previous life impressions.
>
> 2) *Kama*—desire.
>
> 3) *Sukarma*—good karma.
>
> 4) *Vikarma*—bad karma.
>
> 5) *Sukra*-bala—strength of “seed.”
>
> 6) *Mithuna*-vidhi—method of copulation.
>
> 7) *Paurusha*—the personal efforts of the parents.
>
> 8) *Dosha*—affliction.
>
> 9) *Prakriti*—nature.
>
> 10) *Daiva*—divine ordinance.
>
> 1) *Samskara—previous life impressions.* According to Vedic teachings, the living entity is eternal and experiences innumerable lifetimes until achieving final emancipation. Thus, every newborn person comes with a complete package of previous life impressions, desires and activities known as samskaras. Based on these, the living entity takes birth as male, female or third gender.
>
> 2) *Kama—desire.*
>   Every living being has kama or innumerable desires as part of the previous life impressions or samskaras mentioned above. When the living entity
>   desires to experience a lifetime as male, female or third gender, such a lifetime comes to pass.
>
> 3) *Sukarma—good karma.*
>   When the living entity takes birth as male, female or third gender according
>   to desire, such a birth is said to be the result of previous good deeds or
>   sukarma. A birth due to sukarma is evident when the person is happy with
>   the awarded birth and resides in a setting where he or she is treated kindly.
>   Such a person is furthermore endowed with auspicious qualities such as
>   beauty, good health, strength, wealth, talent, intelligence, good parentage,
>   righteousness, renunciation, religiosity, and so on.
>
> 4) *Vikarma—bad karma.*
>   When the living entity is forced to take birth as male, female or third gender
>   against all desire, such a birth is said to be the result of previous misdeeds or
>   vikarma. A birth due to vikarma is evident when the person is unhappy with
>   the awarded birth and resides in a setting where he or she is treated harshly.
>   Such a person is furthermore endowed with inauspicious qualities such as
>   ugliness, ill health, weakness, poverty, lack of talent, foolishness, bad
>   parentage, unrighteousness, excessive attachment, irreligiosity, and so on.
>
> 5) *Sukra-bala—strength of “seed.”*
>   According to the quantity and the quality of the parents’ “seed” at the time of
>   conception, a child is conceived as male, female or third sex. When the
>   father’s sukra or male sexual fluids predominate, a male is produced and
>   when the mother’s sonita or female sexual fluids predominate, the child will
>   be female. If both are equal, the offspring will be of the third sex. Such equal
>   “seed” conceptions are further distinguished as follows: When the “seed” is
>   exactly equal and afflicted, the child will be sterile or have both male and
>   female physical characteristics; when the “seed” is mostly equal but slightly
>   more in terms of the male or female, a third-gender boy or girl will be born
>   respectively, and when the “seed” is mostly equal due to the profuse quantity
>   and strength of both parents, a bisexual child is born. Thus, according to the
>   bala or strength of the parents’ sukra and sonita, various types of male,
>   female and third-gender offspring are produced.
>
> 6) *Mithuna-vidhi—method of copulation.*
>   According to Vedic science, the mithuna-vidhi or method of copulation can
>   also determine a child’s gender by affecting the parents’ “seed” and attracting
>   specific types of living entities to the womb. When upasriptaka or normal
>   copulation is employed, the child will be either male or female but if
>   citrarata or exceptional copulation is engaged in, a third-gender child will
>   likely be the result. Such exceptional methods of copulation are further
>   distinguished as follows: When the parents assume the purushayita or
>   “woman on top” position, the offspring will be a male or female shandha
>   who behaves like the opposite sex; when the wife assumes a complicated
>   position during intercourse and the husband’s semen is weak, the child born
>   will be a vakri with a deformed male organ; when the wife performs oral sex
>   on her husband prior to intercourse and a son is conceived, that boy will be a
>   mukhebhaga who performs oral sex on men, and if the husband performs oral
>   sex on his wife prior to intercourse and a daughter is conceived, that girl will
>   be a svairini who makes love to women. Thus, according to the parents’
>   mithuna-vidhi or method of copulation, various types of male, female and
>   third-gender offspring are produced.
>
> 7) *Paurusha—the personal efforts of the parents.*
>   Parents generally desire heterosexual offspring—especially sons—and Vedic
>   texts offer many helpful practices to assist them in this regard. The parents
>   should keep good sexual health, take invigorating tonics, refrain from
>   overindulgence, assume the upasriptaka or “man on top” position during
>   intercourse, follow proper timing, observe prescribed rituals, consult
>   astrologers, propitiate the gods and so on. At the time of conception, the
>   consciousness of the parents should be peaceful and pure; they must have
>   passion but not excessive lust, anger or detrimental feelings such as jealousy.
>   In this way, the parents should apply personal effort or paurusha to conceive
>   the offspring they desire.
>
> 8) *Dosha—affliction.*
>   Due to previous misdeeds and despite the best efforts of the parents, various
>   afflictions or doshas can arise that result in the birth of sterile or malformed
>   offspring. The word dosha refers to afflictions caused by some imbalance or
>   aggravation of the three bodily substances known as vata, pitta and kapha
>   (also called doshas). When afflictions occur in the sex organs, reproductive
>   fluids, hormones, chromosomes or genes of either the parents or embryo of
>   any sex, offspring are consequently born sterile or sexually malformed to
>   various degrees.
>
> 9) *Prakriti—nature.*
>   When all of the above considerations are taken together they result in the
>   aggregate factor known as prakriti or nature. The workings of material nature
>   are subtle and mysterious yet grossly powerful. According to the stringent
>   laws of prakriti, all living entities are forcibly born among the three genders
>   in a series of countless lifetimes.
>
> 10) *Daiva—divine ordinance.*
>   The ultimate factor in regard to cause of gender is daiva or divine ordinance.
>   Indeed, the laws of nature work according to God’s will and cannot be
>   overruled. It is therefore daiva or divine ordinance that ultimately determines
>   which of the three genders a living entity assumes. The various supernatural
>   causes such as being cursed or blessed by a demigod or saintly person are
>   also included within this category.

**Regardless of one's gender and sexuality, Brahmacharya (celibacy) is necessary for those on the spiritual path.**

Comment: "Kliba [Homosexual men]" - [klIba](http://spokensanskrit.org/index.php?mode=3&script=hk&tran_input=klIba&direct=se) means impotent, not homosexual.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the below reference from Shatapatha Brahmana which is stated by many as reference of Homosexuality.

---

Satapatha Brahmana (2.4.4.19) (https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/sbr/sbe12/sbe1255.htm)

### **"In that same night Mitra implants seed in Varuna, and when it (the moon) wanes, then it is produced from that seed. Now as to why that oblation of curds (payasyâ) to Mitra and Varuna is here exactly analogous (to the Sânnâyya offered at new moon)"**

My opinion on this is, this is just a metaphorical way of explaining the waxing and waning of moon rather than homosexuality.

Answer (score 1):

This is a subject which does not have a black and white answer. There are texts such as the Garuda Purana (as mentioned by the other answer) which illustrate the "sin" of homosexuality, but there are also many texts which illustrate gay, lesbian, transgender life as expressions of "Tritiya Prakriti" or the "third gender".

I came across this website recently (below) which illustrates the Vedic idea very clearly :

http://www.galva108.org/#!TritiyaPrakriti-People-of-the-Third-Sex-1/cu6k/098C3AAD-92BC-4F13-91FB-550C133537CD

Rather than outline the details of the arguments, it may be good to just go to the website itself. It illustrates the origins, names and characteristics of the Vedic interpretation of gay, lesbian, transgender roles. Obviously the Kama Sutras (at least 5,000 ago) and the Khajuharo temples illustrates gay roles, but it should also be noted that there are examples throughout the Itihas, Puran (Mahabharat, Srimat Bhagavatam, etc.) and countless examples of God's, Gandharvins, and enlightened heroes who exhibit dual genders and gay/lesbian activities.

How does one reconcile what the Garuda Purana and some Smritis say with what is written in so many other aspects of the Vedic Literature?  There are many rules for Brahmins, twice born, those following certain vows, etc. which strict sexual laws pertain to.  But this is not to be laws for all people.

The fact that Ardhanarishwar (half male and half female aspects of Shiva /God) exists, or that Ayapan was born from Shiva and Vishnu (Mohini), makes one realize just how profound the Vedas are. All possibilities exist in Conscousness. Different people will be born with different Prakritis and have a devotion to different aspects of God.

This is why there are so many expressions of One Brahman in Vedic Science and so many castes and paths of life.

Ekam sad vipra bahudha vadanti (Upanisads) 
The truth is one, but the wise know it by many names.

In order to know the answer to the question it's important to see the caste, stage in life, and goals in life. The effect of everything is known and understood in terms of action (karma) and understanding the context. For this reason it is explained differently in different aspects of Veda.

Another good website which deals with this is :
http://history-of-hinduism.blogspot.in/p/homosexuality-and-hinduism.html?m=1

It looks at the different aspects of Vedic Literature and how it understands homosexuality differently depending on time and circumstance.

It makes sense that Vedic thought would encompass/incorporate all visions and perspectives of God as well as an understanding of the appropriateness of time and place for everything - - including the resulting effects.

Comment: With all due respect to your thoughts, give me a single quote from any authentic text which supports all this (so called vedic thinking) and acceptance of homosexuals.

Comment: You asked about Hindu and Vedic Scriptures. Do you want me to quote tests that call it a sin (such as in Manu Smriti)? Or to quote behaviors of gay, lesbian or transgender (such as in Itihas , Mahabharat or Kama Sutras, etc.)?

Comment: Your answer claims that Veda's are supporting these people as third gender, I want a single quote from any of the dharma shastras , puranas, itihas, or vedic samhitas, that support your claims, since homosexuality is according to my perception greatest sin in name of lust

Comment: Interesting that you posted this as a "question" but it seems you already felt you had the answer and you just wanted to prove a point. I can come up with quotes... But I have a question for you : is there anywhere that shows that heterosexuality is advocated? (I know that it sounds crazy to ask, but I don't know whether the act it self is ever actually claimed as dharmic leading to "moksha"

Comment: I am just asking is it allowed, since it is a foolish act to get deluded by sexual desires. If people keep up their bamhacharya during prescribed years there is no way such disgusting things happen.

Comment: Its my perception it can be correct or incorrect and I wanted scriptures to guide me and here I can find people with scriptural knowledge to answer it accordingly on Hinduism SE, that is why I posted this question. btw scriptures support and respect kinnaras (transgenders) because it is irrecoverable, but people with normal body's should act accordingly, gay and lesbian are nowhere near aradhanaarishwara, homosexuality is mental problem rather than bodily problem, people who cannot control desires are victims of such problems.

Comment: @Yogi Kinnaras are not transgender people.  Kinnaras are a non-human race who are half-man, half-horse, like centaurs in Greek mythology.  They have perfectly normal genders among them.

Comment: Then what are transgenders referred to as?

Comment: @Yogi I'm not sure whether the notion of transgender even existed. The Manu Smriti and other texts mention the notion of a third gender, but it's not clear to me if that notion refers to hermaphrodites, sodomites, transgendered people, or something else.  In any case, Hindu scripture definitely says that intercourse between two men is a sin.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan For further discussion http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38640/disscussion-on-vedanta-and-sexuality

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan why don't you answer it with that scripture reference

Comment: Ayapan is folkore.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a passage that accepts the existence of homosexuals as simply a fact. An ignorant jiva might be born as a third gender or as a man or as a woman. It is significant that the [punishment for homosexuality](http://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc202068.html) in Manu Smriti is merely bathing. This suggests that homosexuality is not a major sin.

> When the Jiva, who is by nature self-luminous, forgets the Bhagavan,
>   the supreme Teacher and the Soul of all souls, and become identified
>   with the Gunas of Prakriti, then that Jiva, strengthening this
>   identification and attachment through the senses and their objects,
>   engages himself in various actions, and bears the ultimate fruits of
>   these actions by way of embodiments in wombs that are high or low.
>   Sometimes, on the strength of actions of a Sattvika nature, the Jiva
>   attains to worlds of light; sometimes by Rajasika actions, to the
>   world of men full of sorrows and difficulties; and sometimes by
>   Tamasika actions to low worlds of darkness and suffering. **The Jiva who
>   is blinded by ignorance, sometimes is embodied as a man, sometimes as
>   a woman, sometimes as a neuter.**
>
> (Srimad Bhagavata Purana IV.29.26-29)

Ramakrishna Math did not have any problem getting the well-known homosexual intellectual [Christopher Isherwood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_Isherwood#Work_on_Vedanta_and_the_West) to write a biography of Sri Ramakrishna.

Comment: Question is about Homosexuality not about Transgenders.

Comment: It talks about man, woman and neuter, i.e. neither man nor woman in their sexual behavior. Thus the natural interpretation is that neuter includes all who do not behave like straight man and women.

Comment: Do you happen to know Vivekananda's views on homosexuality?

Comment: No, I don't know. However, Isherwood in his book, 'My Guru' says that Swami Prabhavananda. who was at that time the head of the Southern California Vedanta Center, told him that all types of lust (heterosexaul, homosexual, bisexual  etc ) have to be overcome by a spiritual aspirant. A heterosexual person does not have any special advantage over homosexual person. The Swami actually tried very hard to get Isherwood to become a monk. even though he knew that Isherwood was a homosexual. Isherwood even tried to live a celibate life for 6 months but failed.

Answer (score -1):

> मैथुनं तु समासेव्य पुंसि योषिति वा द्विजः । गोयानेऽप्सु दिवा चैव
> सवासाः स्नानमाचरेत् ॥ १७४ ॥
>
> maithunaṃ tu samāsevya puṃsi yoṣiti vā dvijaḥ | goyāne'psu divā caiva
> savāsāḥ snānamācaret || 174 ||
>
> If a twice-born man commits an unnatural offence with a male, or has
> intercourse with a female, in an ox-cart, or in water, or during the
> day, — he should take a bath along with his clothes. — (174)
>
> (Manu Smriti, Chapter 11, Verse 174)

This verse does not specifically condemns homosexuality but just says that you need to wash yourself after intercourse. Also note these shlokas have been omitted from vishuddhi manusmriti.

I see many people here downvoting this just because of there disagreement on something while they point out to vedic literature though dont give any concrete proof on vedas itself.

Vedas themselves have an extremely neutral stand on homosexuality http://aryamantavya.in/manusmriti/?adhyay=11&mantra=174 this is the complete archive of manusmriti and the verses that have been omitted because they contradict manu himself based on the teaching of swami dayanand saraswati.

Thats one secondly https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g9q2jnRPp_4 watch this even if you consider above verse understand the proper explanation here.
Do not force your own meaning of the verses. Sanatana dharma is set of beliefs unlike western religion where you are believer here you are a seeker and ever growing.

Vedas specifically promotes equality and this can be understood here

> As, O God, Thou art for ever the common Lord of all alike, as such we
> invoke thee now. (Rig Veda 4, 32, 13)
>
> There is none high or low amongst you. You are all brethren and
> therefore, strive all together to attain prosperity. (Rg Veda 50, 60,
> 5).
>
> All who can walk are equally entitled to the use of paths and roads.
> (Rig Veda 2, 13, 2)

The below vedic verses apply universally.

To be precise as per the question I should answer this being a vedic believer as Rickross answered they are hindu scriptures but hindus believe differently and they are always free to chose what they believe and vedic way is one of the way in hinduism now to be precise there is nothing that quotes homosexuality in vedas as such i.e. Atharva Veda, Rig Veda , Sama Veda and Yajurv Veda but traditionally homosexuality was accepted and especially transgenders were given high regards and were respected highly for what they were. If you read vedas and you read (Corrupted version of)manusmriti you will realise that there are very evident differences between the two as you see vedas strictly believe there is only one god and idol worship is not allowed while (Corrupted version of)manusmriti mentions several gods again and again. Note that in vedas there is no text against homosexual.

Duties of Wife and husband towards each other (from Vedas)

Wife's Duties

> (1) AtharvaVeda mantra 1/14/1 – A good wife should establish herself
> permanently in her husband’s house just as mountain firmly establishes
> itself on ground.
>
> (2) AtharvaVeda mantra 3/25/1- Wife should long to be in company of
> her husband.
>
> (3) AtharvaVeda mantra 3/25/5- wife should be attracted towards the
> loving attitude of her husband and should always remain sincere to her
> husband.
>
> (4) AtharvaVeda mantra 3/25/6 – wife should discover so much love and
> affection in her husband’s house that she should not remember her
> parent’s house at all.
>
> (5) AtharvaVeda mantra 3/30/2 – wife should conduct herself sweetly
> towards her husband.
>
> (6) AtharvaVeda mantra 4/38/1 – main qualities of wife: (a) Should
> have conquered sensuality  (b) hardworking  (c) possessing best
> behavior  (d) striving to maintain home in best way.
>
> (7) AtharvaVeda mantra 4/38/2 – (a) Preserves and increases husband’s
> money (b) Spends portion of husband’s earnings on Yajya. (c) She is
> always working hard.
>
> (8) AtharvaVeda mantra 4/38/3- (a) She does all household jobs with
> zeal and enthusiasm. (b) Elevates the house in a very mature way. (c)
> Ensures that there is no shortage of milk and milk products in the
> house. (d) Conserves the household earnings.
>
> (9) AtharvaVeda mantra 4/38/4- (a) She remains happy (b) Does not get
> effected by sorrows and anger (c) Makes every one happy with her good
> behavior.
>
> (10) AtharvaVeda mantra 4/38/5- (a) Toils hard from sunrise to sunset.
> (b) Does her work in the light of sun and does not confine herself to
> dark rooms devoid of sunlight.
>
> (11) AtharvaVeda mantra 6/8/1 – wife should be dependent on husband
> just as a creeper completely depends on the tree.
>
> (12) AtharvaVeda mantra 6/8/3 -wife should never even think about
> separating from her husband.
>
> (13) AtharvaVeda mantra 7/47/2- wife should remain healthy, possess
> expertise in household jobs, should be God fearing and remember God’s
> name and possessing divine qualities.
>
> Duties of Husband
>
> (1) AtharvaVeda mantra 1/34/5 – the sweet and loving behavior of
> husband should make the wife to inculcate love and affection towards
> him.
>
> (2) AtharvaVeda mantra 2/30/4 – husband should not hide anything from
> the wife. In this way he shall win over her heart.
>
> (3) AtharvaVeda mantra 5/25/6- he should lead a disciplined, pious
> life.
>
> (4) AtharvaVeda mantra 6/9/2 – husband should try to win over his wife
> with his love.
>
> (5) AtharvaVeda mantra 6/81/1 – husband should lead a disciplined life
> and should be capable of earning money to sustain his married life.
>
> (6) AtharvaVeda mantra 6/89/1 – husband should respect his wife and
> consider his duty to protect the honour of his life.
>
> Common duties
>
> 1). Husband and wife should share everything in common. This sharing
> leads to their long life- AtharvaVeda mantra 2/30/2
>
> 2). AtharvaVeda mantra 6/11/1- wife should possess serene/calm nature
> and husband should be hard working, possessing strong body. This leads
> to generation of brave children.
>
> 3). AtharvaVeda mantra 6/42/1- husband and wife should be completely
> devoid of anger and should work together to accomplish house hold
> tasks.
>
> 4). AtharvaVeda mantra 6/89/2- there should be perfect compatibility
> between husband and wife.
>
> 5). AtharvaVeda mantra 6/36/1- husband –wife should loving gaze at
> each other and their faces should reflect happiness.
>
> 6). AtharvaVeda mantra 7/37/1- husband should never think about
> females other than his wives and wife should dress up decently and
> sensibly covering all body parts.
>
> 7). AtharvaVeda mantra 7/38/1 – wife should firmly hold that she shall
> never be away from her husband’s house and this firm conviction
> prevent the husband from being attracted towards other females.

https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-view-of-Veda-on-marriage-and-responsibility-after-marriage

this is the illustration of what is the vedic take on marriage and resposibility this can also be applied to homosexuality because vedas never differentiated between people born homosexual so there is nothing against them in that.

However, Note:: That most of the acceptance is only applicable for trans or people born with different genetic chromosome. This has nothing to do with the acceptance of current situation of LGBTQ+++.

Even in vedic literature at most we have seen mentions of Third gender, But having sex with same gender is disregarded. Homosexuality is neither openly disregarded nor accepted but if we have to take literal meanings from previous sources while being aligned to science we can safely say that while hinduism do not comment on homosexuality it also doesn't endorse it in any way or form.However it does tries to create a safe heaven for third gender ( typically born in different genetic pool then males or females )

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/23546)

Comment: i think this gives a proper answer to the question because the question explicitly asks reference from vedas and manusmriti is not vedas or vedic text i answered the question by taking reference only from vedas giving answer based on manusmriti actually creates confusion and if  the question was to be asked on hinduism it would have been right to answer it based on manusmriti

Comment: Please understand the structure of Manusmriti. You are required to bathe with clothes in order to expiate the sin. Yes, Manusmriti might list it as a major sin but sin nevertheless. P.S. - Manusmriti also says that in general one should bathe with their clothes.

Comment: the point is this is not based on sexuality. There are set of rules defined by manu maharaj on how to do it. This no where says that you need to bath because you are homosexual. and read the question

Comment: also note the other quote which rickross defined is not considered to be part of manusmriti by arya samaj. Refer vishudhhi manusmriti which has removed lots of contradictory verses from manusmriti.

Comment: @AtharvaPandey - I reiterate that you need to understand Manusmriti. If it was not a sin then there would be no reason for Manusmriti to mention that one needs to bathe. I don't understand what you mean by "set of rules defined by manu maharaj on how to do it". Are you saying that Manusmriti has prescribed how to do homosexual acts ? If so , please post.

Comment: @AtharvaPandey - Can you post screenshot from Vishudhhi manusmriti which says that 11.67 is an interpolation or point to a link ?

Comment: I see that people cannot really take in counter argument and downvoting blindly. One you have not studied this as much as me i have read it and understood it. No where vedic literature condemns this. neither it openly accepts http://aryamantavya.in/manusmriti/?adhyay=11&mantra=174 this is archive of vishudhhi manusmriti the shlokas which are corrupted and has been inserted forcefully have been omitted even the shloka which i explained that has been ommitted

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g9q2jnRPp_4 now hear him who explains and justifies what i said what you call sin. again emphasizing those shlokas have been omitted from manu as they are deemed to be corrupted and forcefully added in the manu which contradicts manu itself at several places.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103924/discussion-between-carmen-sandiego-and-atharva-pandey).

Answer (score -2):

Sri Sri Ravi Shankar [talked](https://www.facebook.com/SriSriRaviShankar/posts/10151832425787536) about this recently:

> Homosexuality has never been considered a crime in Hindu culture. In
>   fact, Lord Ayyappa was born of Hari-Hara (Vishnu & Shiva). It is not a
>   crime in any Smriti. Everyone has male & female elements. According to
>   their dominance, tendencies show up & may change. Nobody should face
>   discrimination because of their sexual preferences. To be branded a
>   criminal for this is absurd.

Comment: Sri Sri Ravishankara is not authentic vedanta Acharya to comment on vedic matters. Lord Ayyappa is child of Shiva (as male) and Shri hari Vishnu' s incarnation Mohini (as female) not both as male.

Comment: @Yogi: Are you an authentic vedanta Acharya?

Comment: Atleast I am authentic vedanta follower, I am no one to be acharya I am kshatriya only Bramhanas are allowed to be a Teacher. Btw I respect Sri Sri Ravishankar but his beliefs are far far away from Vedanta and more close to Yoga and Samkhya Philosophy.

Comment: @Yogi: Are you saying that I cannot post something based on Yoga or Samkhya philosophy? If not, I would request you to take away the downvote. ;)

Comment: The reason for Downvote is not Sri Sri Ravishankar or Yoga/ Samkhya Philosophy, the main reason is you saying that Shri Hari and Lord Shiva produced a child Homosexually, and there is no scripture to support your answer, the main policy of this site is to cite sources with your claims. Even if you consider union of Shri Hari and Lord Shiva then there is no scripture to prove that they had homosexual Relationship. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ayyappan

Comment: @Yogi: Oh okay, I understand your viewpoint. You misunderstood what is said. It is a symbolic 'fusion' of Hari and Hara (as the Wiki article says) to acknowledge homosexuality. I hope this clarifies what is being said.

Comment: "Its not crime in Smriti" as mentioned in your answer,  it's neither accepted in any smriti or Shruti's if you have any smriti or shruti  quotes that accpet it then quote them.If Sri Sri never meant fusion to be homosexuality then why did he mentioned them with his view on homosexuality.

Comment: @AmitSaxena why do people cite story of Harihara to support homosexuality? Clearly, it was Mohini, female energy of Vishnu which united with Shiva. Where did homosexuality come here? According to Shaiva philosophy, nature itself is union of Supreme Purusha (Shiva) and Supreme Parkriti (Shakti). Ganapati was beheaded by Shiva just to his pass his male energy via Trishul and thus Ganesha was formed. Seed of Shiva passed through all this prakriti (personified as Supreme Devi) and it was transformed to Kartikeya.

Comment: @AmitSaxena  Even Soul is Purusha which is sentient and prakriti is insentient and sperm (which has soul) makes insentient egg sentient. So, as progeny is main reason for marriage and sexual intercourse, how homosexuality can even be accepted with above logics?

Comment: Firstly, this is a symbolic story. In my opinion, you are taking it in a too literal sense. Although, you have the right to do so. Secondly, the male energy has female energy in it, and the female energy has some male energy in it. Thirdly, I cannot quote from Smriti because no Smriti mentions it a crime, so that is a Catch-22. Fourthly, I respect your opinions and I can sense multiple reasons why you might not want to acknowledge it. Although, I expect you to respect my answer at the same time.

Comment: @TheDestroyer Please Disscuss this here http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38640/disscussion-on-vedanta-and-sexuality

Comment: lol that is lot of hate for homosexuals! God bless all! :)

Comment: Well Mohini and Shiva copulation has nothing to do with Homosexuality, even in the farthest extent. Mohini was purely female and so the coition is purely Male-female(heterosexual, as in today's term). In fact, God does not have no sexual preference(Homosexual, heterosexual, bisexual et cetera). And as for crime of Homosexuality, it is no crime. It is only that Smriti et cetera say of you cohabit with any thing other than Female, then you must purify yourself again. It is more of getting polluted than crime.

Comment: @AmitSaxena How do you say that no smritis condemn homosexuality? Manu Smriti clearly condemns it and even prescribes punishment for it.

Answer (score -3):

I don't think so, Homosexuality is allowed in Vedic Dharma, its may be written that have an existence but its a Sin. It's against the Purusha and Prakriti coz which denies progeny. Rest upon expert's view. Even going to another wife is a Sin and there is a huge punishment given in Garuda Purana.

You can refer to this link

http://archanavedantam.blogspot.in/2009/07/punishments-for-ur-sins-garuda-purana.html

Comment: Interesting. This Garuda Purana was the basic premises of movie [Anniyan](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anniyan). Isn't it possible that, homosexuality might be a punishment in itself while one's time on earth?

Comment: why exactly did you refer me that link? I mean there is no relevant punishment for homosexuality in that link.

Comment: Blogs isn't valid source to cite. You should cite some reliable/authoritative sources..