# Why was kidnapping such a prevalent custom of marrying women in ancient aryavarta?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, dharma, women, marriage

Bhishma abducted women:

> Meanwhile the son of the ocean-going Ganga heard that king Devaka had a daughter endued with youth and beauty and begotten upon a Sudra wife. Bringing her from her father's abode, Bhishma married her to Vidura of great wisdom. And Vidura begot upon her many children like unto himself in accomplishments.'

-- An excerpt of [Adi Parva Section CXIV](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01115.htm)

Krishna abducted women:

> Of eyes like the lotus petals, and endued with great bravery, Krishna, vanquishing all the kings at a self-choice, bore away the daughter of the king of the Gandharas. Those angry kings, as if they were horses by birth, were yoked unto his nuptial car and were lacerated with the whip.

-- Excerpt of [Drona Parva Section XI](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/m07/m07011.htm)

Duryodhana abducted women:

> Disregarding all the kings, he commanded the maiden to stop. Intoxicated with the pride of energy, and relying upon Bhishma and Drona, king Duryodhana, taking up that maiden on his car, abducted her with force.

Excerpt of [Shanti Parva Section IV](http://sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12a004.htm)

Why was kidnapping such a prevalent custom of marrying women in ancient aryavarta?

Comment: It is not a prevalent custom. There are always consequences and punishments for the wrong-doers.

Comment: Of your three quotes, only third mentions abduction, one done by duryodhana.

Comment: This is like to someone the year 3000 A.D asking 'why were moon landings so frequent during the 20th century?'. It happened only a few times, but because it was so famous, it is remembered for long time in history. you gave 3 examples. Out of how many billions of marriages that would have happened during that time ?? Statistically speaking, how do you know they were 'prevalent' ?

Comment: @Wikash_, if you believe all Hindu epics are fairy tales, what exactly are you doing on this website ?

Comment: @ram it has never been okay to abduct people.

Comment: @Wikash_, false.Kshatriya marriages allow abduction of bride in certain cases. But only for Kshatriyas, not for your beta Romeo from JNU

Comment: @ram nowadays there are jails sentences for such practises. Why did the brahman allow for such a thing and at the same time condome such a marriage?

Comment: @Wikash_, did you read my comment ? I said only for kshatriyas. There are jail sentences today because modern day romeos are not kshatriyas. Just as in the past, there were jail sentences for non-kshatriyas who kidnapped brides. No different from toady.

Comment: @ram Would the Indian government today allow such kidnapping if you can prove you are a kshatriya? I did not think so either. So either the Brahman does a crappy job in the world or we have to take this with a grain of salt.

Comment: @Wikash_, The Indian government today accepts adultery, homosexuality etc. as non-criminal. That's because the people's spirituality has degraded, so the laws/punishments are reduced. Is there any point in punishing a manual laborer for drinking alcohol.. The point still stands that kshatriyas are allowed in certain cases. If you can't deal with it, you are spiritually degraded as well.

Comment: @ram there is no sin on homosexuality in Hinduism. The moral standards have not been degraded but upgraded. Forcefully kidnapping a woman against her will and marrying does not seem like a good situation. In fact it is immoral to do rape of sexual assault any person. "Is there any point in punishing a manual laborer for drinking alcohol." Yes there is. You see intoxication reduces the focus and relying on your senses which can create unsafe situations not only for the labourer but for all who surround this person.

Comment: "you can't deal with it, you are spiritually degraded as well." I can deal with a good person but persons who believe in forcefully marrying someone sounds like a terrible situation what should be forbidden in every yuga. Spiritual degradation? There is no proof of the existence of this spiritual world or any non material things except some nice stories but I can write stories too. Morality is sometimes far fetched in the smriti's and are contradicting other principles (such a the devi purana in which women are uplifted).

Comment: @Wikash_, https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8744/vedas-and-vedic-dharma-on-homosexuality

Comment: @ram exactly my point homosexuality isn't a sin. Also, I am waiting for your reply on my other points.

Comment: @Wikash_, are you purposely acting dumb ? The answer in the link I posted mentions it is a sin with reference from scriptures.

Comment: @ram read the comments carefully. You did not reply to my other points I guess I am right.

Comment: @Wikash_, why would i respond to your comments when you are purposely acting dumb ? the link i posted clearly says it is sin, and you say it is not.

Comment: @ram sorry for the confusion: I meant the comments in your link explain it is not a sin. Also, you did not respond to my other points.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107006/discussion-between-ram-and-wikash).

Answer (score 6):

In scriptures 8 types of marriages are described.

> Manu Smriti 3.21. (They are) the rite of Brahman (Brahma), that of the
>   gods (Daiva), that of the Rishis (Arsha), that of Pragapati
>   (Pragapatya), that of the Asuras (Asura), that of the Gandharvas
>   (Gandharva), that of the Rhashasas (Rakshasa), and that of the Pisakas
>   (Paisaka)

Also, the following verses describe which marriages are suitable for which Varnas.

> 3.23. One may know that the first six according to the order (followed above) are lawful for a Brahmana, the four last for a Kshatriya, and
>   the same four, excepting the Rakshasa rite, for a Vaisya and a Sudra.
>
> 3.24. The sages state that the first four are approved (in the case) of a Brahmana, one, the Rakshasa (rite in the case) of a Kshatriya,
>   and the Asura (marriage in that) of a Vaisya and of a Sudra.

And, in general,

> 3.25. But in these (Institutes of the sacred law) three of the five (last) are declared to be lawful and two unlawful; the Paisaka and the
>   Asura (rites) must never be used

Now,

**Gandharva marriage:**

> 3.32. The voluntary union of a maiden and her lover one must know (to be) the Gandharva rite, which springs from desire and has sexual
>   intercourse for its purpose.

**Rakshasha marriage:**

> 3.33. The forcible abduction of a maiden from her home, while she cries out and weeps, after (her kinsmen) have been slain or wounded
>   and (their houses) broken open, is called the Rakshasa rite.

**Pishacha marriage:**

> 3.34. When (a man) by stealth seduces a girl who is sleeping, intoxicated, or disordered in intellect, that is the eighth, the most
>   base and sinful rite of the Pisakas.

So, when both the bride and bridegroom have no problems in marrying, that marriage comes under the Gandharva Rite. This one is acceptable even if kidnapping is involved.

However, the Rakshasa and Pisacha rites, where marriage takes place without the approval of the maiden and with force or stealth being involved, are generally considered as blameable forms of marriages.

For Kshatriyas, however, the Rakshasa marriage is approved as you can see from one of the verses given above.

Comment: The OP is making an anti-Hindu generalisation. Those who violated women were punished and suffered consequences. Your answer does not address the OP's stated and implicit Q. On the contrary, it implies that rakshasa marriage is acceptable.

Comment: **The OP is making an anti-Hindu generalisation**- That's ur assumption. I don't have any reasons to do the same. I am just seeing the Q as it is and answering it. **Your answer does not address the OP's stated and implicit Q. On the contrary, it implies that rakshasa marriage is acceptable.**- I think it is answering. For Kshatriyas that form of marriage is not entirely prohibited. But generally such marriages are condemned. Verses in support of both my these claims are there in my answer itself. Most characters mentioned in the Q are Kshatriyas too. @moonstar2001

Comment: 'Rakshasa and Pisacha rites...are generally considered as blameable forms of marriages' - can you add references for this statement?

Comment: Ok, I see "two unlawful; the Paisaka and the Asura (rites) must never be used" - so this contradicts your last statement: "For Kshatriyas, however, the Rakshasa marriage is approved" - what does approved mean?

Comment: @sv. Only Pishacha marraige in the quotr of rickross is named sinful.

Comment: @sv. Actually Asura rite and Rakshasa rite are two different types. Asura and Pisacha are the two most censured one. Rakshasa way  is allowed for Kshatriyas.

Comment: “However, the Rakshasa and Pisacha rites...are generally considered blameable forms of marriages" - if you meant Asura & Pishacha, then you can edit/correct it. It's confusing right now.