# Why Lord Krishna justified the abducting of a women forcefully?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna, women

Why Lord Krishna [justified](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01222.htm?fbclid=IwAR1rjUYXGp6qHIQl5NK-uXrvahALniu0wzwe3gHHzbkY3DL6gp6bmFCByRw) abducting a women?

> "Vasudeva answered, 'O bull amongst men, self-choice hath been ordained for the marriage of Kshatriyas. But that is doubtful (in its consequences), O Partha, as we do not know this girl's temper and disposition. In the case of **Kshatriyas that are brave, a forcible abduction for purposes of marriage is applauded, as the learned have said.**

I know [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19466/why-was-kidnapping-such-a-prevalent-custom-of-marrying-women-in-ancient-aryavart) question is something similar to it but I want to know that why Krishna supported this lustful act.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why was kidnapping such a prevalent custom of marrying women in ancient aryavarta?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19466/why-was-kidnapping-such-a-prevalent-custom-of-marrying-women-in-ancient-aryavart)

Comment: customs of cultures vary depending upon time, place, history, and needs of the time. The above was not peculiar to Hindus. The custom above was also followed by the Greeks and many other cultures. The old testament of the Christians gives rules on how to treat young female slaves. In two thousand years people will look back at current customs with the same shock and dismay. Cultural rules change continuously. Each age looks upon itself as enlightened and the past as unenlightened.

Comment: It was not lustful. Out of the 8 vivahas, Rakshasa vivaha is tolerated (although not recommended) for kshatriyas. However, since the question is about Sri Krishna, in that case, Rukmini Devi specifically requested Krishna to come and abduct and marry her, otherwise she would end her own life. So she wasn't actually sad about abduction or crying about her relatives whom Krishna fought off, including her own brother Rukmi. So, it doesn't fall completely under Rakshasa vivhaha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OP mentioned in the content of the question that **In the case of Kshatriyas that are brave, a forcible abduction for purposes of marriage is applauded, as the learned have said**.

The OP also mentioned in the title of the question " ... abducting of a women forcefully?".  **It is a generalised statement**.

---

The [other question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/19466/3869), which the OP had referred to, has an answer under it.

That [answer mentions](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/19468/3869), the following:

**Rakshasha marriage:**

> **Manu Smriti 3.33**. The forcible abduction of a ***maiden*** from her home,
>   while she cries out and weeps, after (her kinsmen) have been slain or
>   wounded and (their houses) broken open, is called the Rakshasa rite.

---

So this Rakshasha marriage, is applicable to **Kshatriya race** only, but not applicable to other Varnas.

The subtlety involved in this type of marriage is, the abductor, a **kshatriya**, should be prepared for the consequences also.

**The relatives of the maiden, whom was abducted, may retaliate, resulting in a war also.**

Comment: Yes, out of the 8 vivahas, Rakshasa vivaha is tolerated (although not recommended) for kshatriyas. However, since the question is about Sri Krishna, in that case, Rukmini Devi specifically requested Krishna to come and abduct and marry her,  otherwise she would end her own life. So she wasn't actually sad about abduction, or crying about her relatives whom Krishna fought off, including her own brother Rukmi. So, it doesn't fall completely under Rakshasa vivhaha.