# Is there any verse in any hindu scripture that doesn't consider homosexuality a crime?

Tags: homosexuality

I have come across the Manusmriti verse that criminalizes homosexuality. However, also kama sutra talks about homosexuality. Is there any verse that doesn't criminalize homosexuality as an offence from any Smriti, Purana, Shruti or any another authoritative Hindu scripture?

Comment: No. There is no verse that condones it. Btw i think you mean "sin" and not "crime"

Comment: Related https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/8744/vedas-and-vedic-dharma-on-homosexuality

Comment: There are puranas which describe such acts but it is not clear whether these are the originally scriptures.

Comment: Most flowering plants are technically homosexual since they have both genders. Thus the verses praising flowering plants like Tulsi, rice, etc. could be interpreted as supporting homosexuality.