# How can a man completely get relieved of curses and sins?

Tags: scripture, sin, prayaschitta

How can a man completely get relieved of curses and sins he committed during his earthly life? Please quote from Hindu scriptures instead of vague answers.

Comment: One and only solution for overcoming all sins, curses, including prarabdha karma is to Just do saranagathi to the Supreme Lord. If, one goes after prayaschittha procedures for the sins one has committed and to overcome curses, one life time will not be sufficient.

Comment: @K--thinking to be refined. Not the answer I expected.

Comment: @@Parthasaratthy Raghavan - it is not an answer. That is why I added it in the comments . But, ultimately Saranagathi is the only way out, whether one likes it or not, is a different matter all together. You know the Rama charama slokas, Krishna Charama sloka and VarAha charama sloka. Yes, there are prayaschittha karmas for overcoming sins. Even doing trikala sandhyavandanam can over come sins done every day. Sandhyavandanam includes Kamokarshit manyoraykarshan matras japam too...

Comment: @K--I understood you have not put in answer---you have said about saranagathi and sandhyavandanam will relieve part of sins only. Apart from these one more important aspect is there which I will give an answer in due course.

Comment: @@Parthasarathy Raghavan - No, I didn't say that saranagathi will remove only part of sins. Saranagathi will destroy ones prarabdha karma also. Please read Swami Desikan's Nyasa vimsati. It should clarify things, Hopefully. But, I am not contesting your question. It is good question. There are many prayaschittha methods and I am not aware of them. Nor these prayaschittha methods prescribed in scriptures possible in this Kaliyuga, I suppose.

Comment: @K--true-- I have read nyasa vimsathi. Let me give the answer in due course for this. All puranic which is history we will keep referring and keep on arguing. No end limit.

Comment: @ParthasarathyRaghavan We can get relieved from sins but not from curses. Many Puranas say so. If you want examples, i can give them as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A man can be relieved from curses and sins completely  he committed during his earthly life when he dies followed by his wife also dies in the same pyre and loses here life. This is the best parikara.
கணவன் செய்த எல்லா பாவங்களும், அவனுடைய மனைவி கணவனுடன் உடன்கட்டை ஏறுவதால் பரிகாரமாகி விடும்.

Source Garuda puranam under prayaschitha chapter.

Comment: Please use English script when quoting. It is better to quote only from Sanskrit but if quoting from any other languages, please provide as accurate and complete translation as possible.

Answer (score 4):

A practical and easy prayaschitta measure that is effective in removing all kinds of sins is called **Tula Purusha**.

It involves the making of gifts(donation of) any substance equal to one's own weight to a male human being .Most people make such donations to temples of male Gods.

> [image]
>
> 80. The chandrayana penance, the eating of unripe barley, **the form of making a gift, called the Tulapurusha, [I, e., making a gift of such a
>       quantity of any substance as is equal in weight to a male human
>       being]**, and the act of walking behind cows, — **these put an end to all
>       kinds of sin.**(Parashara Smriti ,Chapter 12,verse 80)

I have seen many people here are concerned about what to do when they know that they have committed a sin.Most people have not read the Scriptures so they are not aware of the prayaschitta measures given therein.

Also,many measures that are given in Shastras are very difficult to perform,like the Chandrayana penance,Krikkhara penance,Tapta Krikkhara penance,Samtapana Krrikkhra penance etc. all of which involves prolonged fasting.

So,for such situations,when one does not know which specific prayaschitta is to be performed, the Tula Purusha remedy comes very handy.And it can be done by anyone without any restrictions.

And,its more effective a remedy in Kali Yuga in particular because of the following verse:

> [image]
>
> 23. " Self-mortification is the rule in the Krita age ; knowledge is said (to be the same) in the Treta ; in the Dvapara, (they) say
>       sacrifice (to the gods to be) the sole (rule) ; **and charity alone in
>       the Kali age.**(Parashara Smriti,Chapter 1,verse 23)

Comment: I am not undermining you or anything but I have a doubt - in the first verse it says "The chandrayana penance, .... human being] AND act of walking behind cows...."

Comment: (cont.) It specifically says AND (rather than OR) -  don't you think it would mean ALL the things rather than any one thing?

Comment: No, they are separately capable of removing the sins .. Chnadrayana measure in itself is a standalone remedy .. it is quite difficult to perform as well .. so, along with it one does not need to perform any other remedies. @JohnRay

Comment: Thanks. Hey, I have one more doubt - does doing this get rid of even grave sins of a person like for the ones specific hells are prescribed?

Comment: @JohnRay Yes, it is supposed to eradicate all sorts of sins... Also, this is Kali Yuga .. and in this age charity is considered the most effective way ..

Answer (score 4):

By reciting 1008 names of Mahadeva.

Vyasa told Yudhisthira that if if you recite the 1008 names of Mahadeva, he will be gratified and he will be otain the fruit of your wishes.

> "Vaisampayana said, 'After Vasudeva had ceased to speak, the great Yogin, viz. the Island-born Krishna, addressed Yudhisthira, saying,--O son, do thou recite this hymn consisting of the thousand and eight names of Mahadeva, and let Maheswara be gratified with thee. In former days, O son, I was engaged in the practice of severe austerities on the breast of the mountains of Meru from desire of obtaining a son. It is this very hymn that was recited by me. As the reward of this, I obtained the fruition of all my wishes, O son of Pandu. Thou wilt also, by reciting this same hymn, obtain from Sarva the fruition of all thy wishes.

Parashurama also recited the hymn of 1008 names of Shiva an got rid of his sin.

> Then Jamadagni's son, that foremost of all righteous persons, shining like the Sun with blazing splendour in the midst of that conclave of Rishis, said unto the son of Kunti these words;--I was afflicted with the sin, O eldest son of Pandu, of Brahmanicide for having slain my brothers who were all learned Brahmanas. For purifying myself, I sought the protection, O king, of Mahadeva. I hymned the praises of the great Deity by reciting his names. At this, Bhava became gratified with me and gave me a battle-axe and many other celestial weapons. And he said unto me,--Thou shalt be freed from sin and thou shalt be invincible in battle; Death himself shall not succeed in overcoming thee for thou shalt be freed from disease.--Even thus did the illustrious and crested Deity of auspicious form said unto me. Through the grace of that Deity of supreme intelligence I obtained all that He had said.

Rishi Asita-Devala got cursed by Indra because of which, he lost all his merit.

> Then the Rishi Asita-Devala, addressing the royal son of Pandu, said,--In former days, O son of Kunti, through the curse of Sakra, all my merit due to the acts of righteousness I had performed, was destroyed. The puissant Mahadeva it was who kindly gave me back that merit together with great fame and a long life.

There are many instances how people got relieved of curses, sins, and got boons by reciting 1008 names of Mahadeva.

---

By [bathing in Pushkara Tirtha](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03082.htm), one is free of all sins.

> That man in special who visits Pushkara on the full moon of the month of Karttika, acquireth ever-lasting regions in the abode of Brahma. He that thinketh with joined hands morning and evening, of the Pushkara, practically batheth, O Bharata, in every tirtha. Whether a male or a female, whatever sins one may commit since birth, are all destroyed as soon as one batheth in Pushkara.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer is really long time (millions of [kalpas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindu_units_of_time#For_Brahma)). Scriptural answer is:

> भुङ्के हि स्वकृतं कर्म सर्वत्रापि च भारते। 
> शुभाशुभं च यत्किचित्स्वकर्मफलभुक्पुमान् ॥१६॥ 
> नाभुक्तं क्षीयते कर्मकल्पकोटिशतैरपि। 
> अवश्यमेव भोक्तव्यं कृतं कर्म शुभाशुभम् ॥१७॥
>
> One gets the result of one's own deeds in the land of Bharata. Whatever good or bad deeds are performed by him, he surely has to face the result.
>
> Because **the deeds never vanish even after the lapse of hundreds and crores of kalpas**, one has to reap the result of the good or bad deeds performed by him.
>
> जन्म भोगावशेषे च सर्वेषा कृतकर्मणाम्। 
> अनुरूपं च तेषां वै भारतेऽन्यत्र चैव हि ॥१९॥
>
> If the results of some of the deeds are left out in one birth, he has to face them in the next birth.
>
> ([Brahma-vaivarta-purāṇa, Prakṛti-kāṇḍa, Ch. 37](http://www.hinduscriptures.in/Content/Articles/PDFs/30776/77f_chapter_67.pdf))

Also see: [Is our destiny predetermined? If yes, then why do our actions affect our karma?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/2407/2995)

Comment: As per the answer,the results of the deeds{ good and bad},are carried forward.The result of the good deeds, get accumulated as "Punya". Punya  should be collected in a birth by doing good deeds, Punya increases,and the count on curses,can be kept as low as possible.

Comment: This is against concept of Moksha. Without annihilating Karma, we can't get Moksha. If this is true, then only way to get Moksha is by reaping his Karma  and doing Nishkama Karma like Karma yogis.

Comment: In some rare cases, a Curse later acts like a Boon.In the bridge building process in Ramayana, a curse on one of the Vanara{Nal-Neel}, acted like  a boon, in the service of Sri Rama.Thereafter, the stones thrown in water, became “floating stones” and the part of the bridge to Lanka.

Comment: @TheDestroyer I think OP is only interested in knowing how long it will take to break the cycle of birth and rebirth without actively doing anything (bhakti or jnana). He did not ask how to break the cycle for which I gave the other link. BVP could be corrupted but the verse I quoted makes lot of sense.

Comment: @sv. OP says " during his earthly life". So, this includes Jnana and Bhakthi. Well, **making sense** is subjective and different people have different opinions.

Comment: @TheDestroyer For a man living in a remote village in Africa, there is neither bhakti nor jnana, only karma path applies to him. So my answer is based on karma. OP is saying 'sins committed during earthly life', he did not say what else the man was doing (bhakti or jnana). As such the question is a very broad one.

Comment: @sv. A Person living in Africa may worship God of other Religion and that works in different way to Hinduism. Who knows laws work them differently as mentioned in Bible or Quran. He was destined to born in that Religion. So, that is different thing. But in view of Hinduism or Sanatana Dharma, Jnana and Bhakti come to play their role. You can't say Karma alone works. They is possibility of getting Moksha by Jnana and Bhakthi. Indeed, OP has some Karmic connection with Sanatana Dharma and that's the reason he is interested in this site.

Comment: Repentance is a first step. Lifestyle change for better is second step. Humble prayer as Sarvasva saranagathi to Supreme is the third.

Comment: Sins make up a small portion of karma. They can be removed, as it is referenced quite a lot. Other karma cannot, but it is not necessarily good or bad, it could just make you different.