# Is it true that by doing chairty one can get rid of his sin?

Tags: sin, charity

Is it true that by doing charity (giving daan) one can get rid of his sin ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's true.

> Manu Smriti 11.227. By confession, by repentance, by austerity, and by
> reciting (the Veda) a sinner is freed from guilt, **and in case no
> other course is possible, by liberality.**

Similar verse from Baudhayana Dharma Sutras (from [here](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc202132.html)):

> Baudhāyana (Do.).—‘Abandonment, Austerity, Charity, Repentance,
> Proclaiming the deed, Devotion to Learning, and Bath,—these are the
> seven factors in the destruction of Sin.’

So by liberality or charity one get rid of their sins.

In Kali Yuga making gifts is even more effective and according to some scriptures the foremost method. Tula Purusha is an effective method of getting rid of one's sins through charity. See this answer -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17008/4732

Comment: 1) If a child/teenager donates from parent's money, parents are freed of sins or child. Same question for age old people who don't earn 2) let's suppose there is a bad sin(not great sin like crimes) , one commits it now he/she leave it forever but don't do prayyachit recommend by smritis but just donates whole heartedly. Can he consider him free from sin??

Comment: Suppose the parents have given their child some money then that wealth no longer belongs to the parents it's owner is the child. Now if the child donates that money to the needy then he earns Punya and destroys sins by doing so. @Hope

Comment: Please answer second question like a person is recommend Prājāpatya’ penance, santapam penance or any xyz penance but he doesn't do it and leave that bad act forever and just do charity (but not that penance). Is he free from sin????

Comment: In that case one needs to consult a Punditji who can tell donating exactly what will be equivalent to those penances. @Hope Highly meritorious gifts are those where land, gold, cows,maiden daughter (in marriage) etc. are gifted.