Prayaschitta for various sins committed by a person
What are the methods of expiation given in the Hindu texts for the various sins one has committed and genuinely want to rectify them and become sinless. Sins like beating someone ,using very vulgar language and demeaning some one, having bad intent for someone , killing someone, disrespecting a deity by thoughts deeds or actions , breaking a promise etc.
And does doing a pryaschitta completely remove the bad effects of karma one doesn’t want to face ? Does repeated chanting of mantras of deities, Gayatri mantra , 108 names of Ganga help in becoming sinless? Also are there any puranas or books which deal with the punishments and prayaschittas for the sins one commit knowingly or unknowingly? Thank you.

For different types of sins different prayaschitta methods are prescribe in scriptures.

@Rickross could you please mention the name of the scriptures . Thank you.

Many scriptures like Smritis and Puranas discuss this topic .. so it will be very broad to cover everything in one answer.

In general fasting on holy days clear sins,taking names of gods (your favorite deity's name) also clears sins. Chanting the Guru given mantra also clears sins. Apart from this see this answer (it involves charity or dana) -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/17008/4732
