# What is Hinduism's view on porn?

Tags: scripture, belief

What is Hinduism's view on porn?

Please include verses to back it up.
If there are no verses than what are the opinions of general public or people known in the research area?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religious_views_on_pornography#Hinduism

Comment: You may find some answers [here](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/697/2995). "opinions of general public" - opinion based questions are not generally recommended here because there cannot be a single correct answer for such questions.

Comment: see my answer to question here - http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/697/what-does-hinduism-say-about-masturbation/3760#3760

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda forgive me if I missed it but the answered you referenced doesn't even mention pornography.  In addition I plan to add a bounty to this question is that okay?

Comment: I think that Hinduism has no any view on pornography simply because Hindu scriptures do not talk about it, ie they do not recognise such a thing called pornography.

Comment: 1. Watching other couples being intimate is a sin according to Hinduism. This is evidenced by several stories of people having to suffer the consequences of such (accidental or intentional) voyeurism . Pandu raja, Renuka devi (wife of Jamadagni) are two such examples. 2. Gratuitous sating of the senses is not acceptable in Hinduism. 3. According to Hinduism , one must engage in conjugal sport only with one's dharmic spouse.

Comment: @WIlliam see again in my answer - "Unrighteousness may take three forms, namely, physical, verbal, and mental, depending upon the condition of its functioning. Physical unrighteousness manifests itself asa cruelty (himsa), theft (steya), and sexual perversion (pratisiddha maithuna)..."

Comment: @William I see that you added a Wikipedia link, so you are looking to update the Wikipedia article with some credible sources?

Comment: @sv. that is a really good idea.  I do not have a wikipedia account but that is still a good idea.  I was just trying to demonstrate how little information about this is available on the web.

Comment: Nice Q. The term "Hinduism" supposedly came into existence due to Iranian Muslims in 7th century or after. So if you ask the view from that perspective then the views are usually conservative. However if you meant by Hinduism as the "culture" which evolved in Indian subcontinent, then you may get liberal views as well. When something controversial like "pornography" or "sexuality" comes forward, usually conservative people be more judgemental on good vs bad, rather than describing it (like wikipedia). Do you seek advise on pornography or historical outline? There may not be verses though.

Comment: Swami Vivekananda says "Unchaste imagination is as bad as unchaste action. Controlled desire leads to the highest result. transform the sexual energy into spiritual energy, but do not emasculate, because that is throwing away the power." Complete Works, V7, p 69; available here under the heading 'Inspired Talks' Sub-heading 'Thursday, July 25' http://cwsv.belurmath.org/volume_7/vol_7_frame.htm

Comment: @moonstar2001 King Pandu was (directly) killed because of curse of Rishi Kindama, because he killed the sage who was having coitus with his wife, and not because he saw them having coitus. Btw what is story of Renuka Devi?

Comment: @Yogi Yes you are right. I misquoted. Pandu was cursed because he was unashamed of his action and behaved in a way that is unbecoming of a kshatriya. Renuka , on her way to fetch water from the river, paused to watch a couple sport and was late in getting back. Jamadagni realised this and ordered his sons to kill their mother to remove her sin.

Comment: @Rickross Um, I reverted my edit....

Answer (score 45, accepted):

In Hinduism we have the concept of "Ashtavidha Mithuna" .i.e 8 forms of copulation all of which are equivalent or equally important in a given context .

For example,from the book [Essence of Dharma Sindhu](http://www.kamakoti.org/kamakoti/dharmasindhu/bookindex.php) :

> During the Upavaasa time(fasting time), one should not take water too
>   many times, should not chew betel leaves/nuts, should not sleep, nor
>   resort to **Ashtavidha Mithuna** ie. **think of sex, hear provocative
>   songs, viewing objectionable material**, secret gossip, take vows and
>   decisions and refrain from acts other than related to devotion.

The [Daksha Smriti](http://www.yoga-age.com/modern/brahma.html) says:

> Thinking of a woman or her picture, praising a woman or her picture,
>   sporting with a woman or her picture, glancing at a woman or her
>   picture, secretly talking to a woman, thinking of a sinful action
>   towards a woman actuated by sensuality, determining upon the sinful
>   action, and bodily action resulting in the discharge of semen are the
>   eight characteristics of copulation; and Brahmacharya is quite
>   contrary to all these eight indications.

Now,viewing/reading pornography comes under one or more types(of copulation) given above.
So,the point is, if one form of copulation is objectionable in a given context then any other 7 forms are equally objectionable.

**Hence, if doing actual copulation is offensive or objectionable in a context/situation then viewing porn is equally offensive or objectionable in that context/situation.**

**For example,in Hinduism "Parastreegamana" (having sex with other's  wife ) is a sin.So ,whatever i have posted above would imply that, viewing pornography(which is  nothing but watching a parastree, or someone who's not one's wife, having sex) is also a similar kind of sin.**

Edit-The following texts are taken from an abridged version Yajnavalkya Smriti:

> 36. A householder should preferably wear a white cloth. Hair, moustache and nails shall he kept always clean. He should not take
>       food unless supervised by his wife.......
> 37. **He should never gaze at fire, sun, a nude woman, a woman engaged in a sexual act, wine, faeces, etc.** He should never sleep with his
>       head to the west.

[image]

And more from the same Smriti:

> 13 — 20. There are many Upapātakas (minor sins and turpitude).......
>   causing others to break their vow, selfish ventures, cohabitation with
>   an alcoholic, forsaking of one's study of Vedas, sacred fires, child,
>   and kinsmen, **perusal of illegal and unholy literature,** selling of
>   oneself or one's own wife, all these are Upapātakas.

The above texts in bold have direct reference to pornography or sexually explicit materials i guess.And as per them,viewing pornography comes under "minor sins" or *Upapaatakas*.(*Mahapaatakas* are grave sins)

In Hinduism, maintaining Brahmacharya(celibacy) is of utmost significance for spiritual aspirants.

Comment: Upapaatakas are described only in Rashtramimamsaa, not in individual spiritual context. Also, Brahmacharya is not that important as you are portraying it to be. Ashramadharma has phases where brahmacharya is important but not the entire life. Also, indeed, sex with other's wife is a sin, but what if the woman is unmarried?

Comment: Is [Dharmasindhu](http://kamakoti.org/kamako60xxoiti/dharmasindhu/bookindex.php) referred here as a primary source, a Vedic literature? "hear provocative songs, viewing objectionable material". In older times as latest as 1000 years ago, "listening to songs" & "looking at provocative material" was not available to general people. Recording & photography were invented couple hundred years ago. Even the paper was invented few centuries ago. I think such links represent modern thinking of some individuals rather than ancient Hinduism. They may be right, but they may not represent ancient.

Comment: @iammilind Dharma Sindhu, as the name suggests, is the compilation or essence of all the Dharma Shastras..they collect the information from Manu,Parashara,Vashista and other Smritis..so its a perfectly valid source for questions like this...paintings, songs are there from time immemorial..even when paper was not there..

Comment: @VineetMenon Im not sure what u meant by Upapaatakas are described only in Rashtramimamsaa, not in individual spiritual context...**Also, Brahmacharya is not that important as you are portraying it to be**. This is not at all about celibacy..its about watching woman whos not ur legal wife having sex..Watching sexual activity and actually doing it are similar kinds of activities..my answer is based on this core idea..

Comment: @Rickross can you provide the link/source of the translation to Yajnavalkya Smriti from which you have quoted? Thanks

Comment: I have seen ur message in the room but can't post a reply unless you allow me permission @IamThat

Answer (score 17):

The advice is not to watch it. Bhishma was asked by Yudhishthira the following question:

> 'What is the appearance presented by those that are wicked, and what
> are those acts which they that are called good are to do? Explain to
> me this, o holy one! Indeed, tell me what the indications are of the
> good and wicked?'
>
> Bhishma said, "They that are wicked are evil in their practices, ungovernable or incapable of being kept within the restraints of rules, and foul mouthed. They, on the other hand, they are good, are always good in their acts. .......**One should  never cast one's eyes on a naked woman, nor
> a naked man**. One should never indulge in sexual congress except in
> privacy................."

Mahabharata, Anusasana Parva, Section CLXII

Comment: Without some additional context what you quoted can be misinterpreted. What about one's legally wedded spouse?

Comment: Bhishma says naked woman. I think he would have said naked wife if he wanted to mention spouse.

Comment: I have added some additional material to provide the context.

Answer (score 13):

#### Some background

For Hindus, religion is the means of realizing dharma (virtuous deeds), artha (wealth, career), kāma (desire or pleasure of senses) and mokṣa (self-realization). Together these four are called [Puruṣārthas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puru%E1%B9%A3%C4%81rtha) (objects of human pursuit).

Kāma is ephemeral happiness we derive from worldly pleasures while mokṣa is everlasting happiness.

Dharma should be a life-long objective. The pursuit of artha (wealth, material needs) and kāma (desire, love) must be given up at a certain stage in a man's life.

**But why are artha and kāma needed in first place?**

> A man needs money and material goods to live in this world. As for kāma or carnal desire, it is needed so that children may be born according to their past karma.

**Can't we just renounce everything and become a [sannyasi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sannyasa)?**

> Until we have lived out our karma we too will have to be in this world. In this way if we want to give a "chance" to others, we have to earn money and experience kāma so that they these others may be born again. We need householders to feed sannyasins who have given up karma. It would not be practical for all people in this world to become ascetics. **The [śāstras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shastra) extol householders as the backbone of society since they live, or are expected to live, according to the dictates of dharma and fulfill the requirements of student-bachelors and ascetics.**

---

#### Now, to address your question and [the likes of it](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/697/what-does-hinduism-say-about-masturbation).

**Can the Student or Ascetic do it?**

> In the gurukula, the celibate-student is brought under strict discipline. That saves him from being swept away by animal passion.
> Though we talk of animal passion, we must note that animals mate only during a particular season. They have the sexual urge only when the female of the species is ready for pregnancy. Man is baser in such matters. [Brahmacarya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmacharya) helps to control the carnal urge as it first shows up. Then, in the householder's life, since kāma is made subservient to dharma, the passions are kept under check.

**What about the Householder?**

> [Saṃskāras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanskara_(rite_of_passage)) such as marriage are akin to making chillis less hot by tempering them with [ghee](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghee): they serve to tame the natural urges. We add ghee to the chilli so that it does not inflame the intestines. **Carnal pleasure and worldly enjoyment are part of the life of a householder but they are kept within certain limits so that he is not overcome by them.**
>
> After completing one's student-bachelorhood and acquiring learning and good qualities, one must marry so as to perform religious rites and live a life guided by dharma. Marriage is included among the forty samskaras, which fact shows that it is a sacred rite that sanctifies life. Just as upanayana is preliminary (ptirvanga) to the student-bachelor's stage of life, marriage is preliminary to that of the householder. **Its purpose is disciplining the senses and the basis for the performance of various duties.**
>
> The householder's life is not to be taken to mean merely the enjoyment of sensual pleasure along with the carrying out of duties that mean good to the world. The fact is that the śāstras have formulated this stage of life in such a way as to make kāma itself instinct with dharma. "Dharma" means essentially bringing everything within certain limits, under a certain discipline and decorum. **Kāma must be inspired by dharma, i.e., one must bridle one's passions in one's conjugal life, so that, step by step, the carnal urge will lose its keenness and eventually one will gain the mellowness to graduate to sannyāsa.**
>
> That stage, though, comes later. But at first, even now, in the householder's stage of life, the passions have to be curbed, little by little, but not forcibly.

Reference:

*[Hindu Dharma: The Universal Way of Life](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/8172760558)*, [Swami Chandrasekarendra Saraswati](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chandrashekarendra_Saraswati)

Answer (score 7):

Viewing pornography is a **sin** according to Hinduism

The definition of [pornography](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/pornography) is

> Printed or visual material containing the explicit description or
>   display of sexual organs or activity, **intended to stimulate sexual
>   excitement**.

The following words by Vinayaka to Parashurama clarifies that viewing pornography is a sin

> **Whether out of carnal desire or otherwise**, if a person sees another person inclined to sexual intercourse, he shall have to suffer
>   certainly separation from his wife in the course of seven births. He
>   is a base man—he who looks at the buttocks, breasts and face of
>   another man's wife, his mother, sister or daughter.
>
> [[45-46,Chapter 41: The story of Bhargava(continued), Part II, The
>   Brahmanda Purana]](https://doc-14-bc-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/securesc/ha0ro937gcuc7l7deffksulhg5h7mbp1/pl872ta0mnqkcc0m2317u3m5umrpblnk/1560513600000/02058467015715614041/*/0ByTrbPQHgxJdZkV6Q2R5QlNacDA)

Answer (score 2):

Leave pornography

Even casting lustful eyes on women is very fatal

*Mahabharat Anushasan pava Chapter cxlv verse 50-51*

> Those men of foolish understandings who cast their wicked eyes upon
> the married wives of other men, become cursed with cogenetial
> *blindness* on account of that sinfulness of theirs
> Those men who,
> ***impelled by desire in their hearts, cast their eyes on naked women,***
> those men of wicked deeds take birth in this world to pass their ***whole
> lives in one continuous disease.***

Answer (score 1):

The term "pornography" is relatively new for any religion. Some people relate it to vulgarity, some people treat it as a sin and some people are OK (on peace) with it. This is more of a local belief irrespective of any religion.
I presume that, you want to know the overall view of Hinduism on "Pornography", rather than just the current populace thinking. Let's revisit the 2 definitions from Wikipedia which already has sources cited:

**[Pornography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pornography)** is the portrayal of sexual subject matter for the purpose of sexual arousal. Pornography may be **presented in a variety of media**, including books, magazines, postcards, photographs, **sculpture**, drawing, painting, animation, sound recording, film, video, and video games.

and

**[Hinduism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hinduism)** is a religion, or a way of life. Hinduism has been called the "oldest religion" in the world, and some practitioners and scholars refer to it as Sanātana Dharma.

---

Due to "porn" being a modern word, ofcourse there cannot be *"scriptures"* reference of it. Hence the liberals usually put forward the [Khajuraho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khajuraho_Group_of_Monuments#Arts_and_sculpture) *"sculptures"*, which were created in a temple during 10th century in Madhya Pradesh, India. This is an open for public temple & recognized by the government.
Around 10% of such sculptures are erotic, which philosophically depicts that a small part of life is human's sexuality as well. Here is a nice [video link (41:00)](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=VcThFnztv4w&feature=youtu.be) link from an old movie, which explains in brief about this carvings of Khajuraho temple. Incidentally the actor is late Vijay Anand, who went on to become the head of film censor board of India. He also had the liberalized views.

**##Spoiler##**: Sexually explicit images ahead, which may deviate [some people](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15138/what-is-hinduisms-view-on-porn/15385?noredirect=1#comment37931_15385) from the path of *Dharma*. Click on it with proper discretion.

> [image]
>  [image]

Above Khajuraho pictures depict an orgy of multiple sex partners & also homosexuality at certain extent. Now, such erotic arts & sculptures are not limited to only this temple.
[14 Temples In India Where You Get A Lot More Than Just The Traditional Prasad](http://www.indiatimes.com/culture/who-we-are/14-temples-in-india-where-you-get-a-lot-more-than-just-the-traditional-prasad-231878.html)

---

As you see, this carvings are present in the "temples", which shows a very liberal view on "depiction of sexuality" in older era. In fact, **those people didn't see sex or porn with a "shock value"**. However, with foreign invasions starting from 13-14 century and admixing of other cultures, the sexuality created more of a negative sentiment among the general population. It was no more considered as "way of life". May be for the good reasons (to avoid inter mixes of races, diseases, adultery, ...), various moral codes were imposed, like "don't do this, don't look at that, ...".

If someone considers "pornography" as "bad", then that "bad" is created due to making "sex" as taboo. Anything which is made taboo or unnaturally restricted, results in distortion. Flowing water remains fresh, while the blocked water becomes stale.

However, going by the definition **for "pornography", "Hinduism" is/was an accepting culture**; though the current population may not be. I would also recommend to refer below answer which nicely discusses about Hindu texts by Vedic philosopher [Muni VAtsyAyana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kama_Sutra) on exploring sexuality:
[What does Hinduism say about masturbation?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/704/1049)

Comment: By this answer, do you mean sex  or watching it was rampant?

Comment: Who cares what Vatsayan has to say on Dharmic questions?One need to consult the Dharma Shastras  to be precise.A must dowvote able post for me although i have not.

Comment: You didn't answer my first question, **Do you mean sex or watching it was rampant?** which is very important for me to understand your answer.

Comment: @TheDestroyer, I read your 2nd comment to be judgemental. Usually I skip them to avoid arguments. You can see some users talk about Dharma & ethics as of monopoly. I let them be happy. If you genuinely want know, then here it is. Sex or watching it were not rampant. Neither I have used that term in my answer. Rather in older times "sex" was just normal part of life practices, like eating food or drinking water. They were presented as art like today's cinema. There was NO shock value with it. Vulgarity in Pornography was born due to making sex as taboo. When water is restricted, it destorts.

Comment: @iammilind I was sarcastic though bit rude as it looked like "western thinking". People on Quora support all kind of their own whims and fantasies by citing Kamasutra and these monuments. Prostitution was present in Ancient India as Puranas mention many stories. I agree with your answer unless it makes rampant. With growing Kali, "Taboos" are really helpful. See how sex education in west is making 13 year old teens getting pregnant. (1)

Comment: @iammilind People these days say "Sex was not all taboo in Ancient India and Women were Topless (especially people on Quora)" and they want people be like that now without considering other factors such as **degree of Spirituality and  Population in Ancient times**. May be even though it was not taboo, present conditions are better. **"Lust can't be satiated by watching Porn, it only just increases it"**. With making Pornography accessible, can anyone expect people becoming Saints by controlling Indriyas? Also, we can't just determine way of living with just 10% of monuments.(2/2)

Comment: I put the images in spoiler tags and undeleted your answer.

Comment: Khajuraho temple built by the Chandalas as  kings.. It has some permanent explicit erotic sculpture outside the temple. But no erotic presentations inside  after entering towards the sanctum.The way to salvation is through Dharma, Artha, Kama and  Moksha.  These are just sides of a coin or facets of dice. One can with proper mind attitude pass through the erotic corridor and next visit the deity in temple Sanctum with equanimity without feeling of guilt. With same devotion we can read in Sthrothras, long hands of Lord Rama or the Devi's  symmetric feminine beauteous form.

Comment: Idols/Images are not  pramana for right knowledge about dress code, sex, etc. Only canonical literature of vedic religion is shastra pramana for right knowledge of dharma, kama, artha and moksha.

Comment: Homosexuality is sin (refer Manu ch 11) . So, your logic of linking image to justify a topic is nuisance.