# Unholy literature and media, what our scripture says

Tags: belief, sin, smriti, hell, lust

I want to know what scripture says on unholy sources of entertainment like a film promoting alcohol, smoking, or literature magazine promoting sexualization.

What do scripture recommend us?

Comment: See this -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15138/4732

Comment: @Rickross this is not for porn. I am asking for movies, anime, magzines . I have left porn by this verse :Those men who, impelled by desire in their hearts, cast their eyes on naked women, those men of wicked deeds take birth in this world to pass their whole lives in one continuous disease. (Source: Anusasana Parva: Section CXLV verse 51)

Comment: @Rickross add this verse in your answer given here from mahabharat

Comment: I thought you're asking about pornographic magazines and literature. Also it's not good for me to add that verse since it was you who found it and I wasn't aware of it. You can add an answer there with that verse in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

References of films obviously can not be found in scriptures. But I believe the closest one get to this topic is [Manu 11.65](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201942.html) which talks about reading "bad books" (asat shastra)

> अनाहिताग्निता स्तेयं ऋणानामनपक्रिया ।
>  असत्शास्त्राधिगमनं
> कौशीलव्यस्य च क्रिया ॥ ६५ ॥
>
> anāhitāgnitā steyaṃ ṛṇānāmanapakriyā |
> **asatśāstrādhigamanaṃ** kauśīlavyasya ca kriyā || 65 ||
>
> Omission of fire-laying, theft, non-payment of debts, **studying bad
> books**, and the practising of the histrionic art.—(65)

All these are some of the many offences that lead to loss of caste (Jatibhramsha).

Commentator Medhatithi thinks here bad books refer to texts which go against the principles mentioned in the Hindu scriptures.

> Theft—of articles other than those specifically named in this
> connection.
>
> ‘Debts.’—This refers to the non-performance of those acts that have
> been laid down as paying off the ‘four debts’ (to the Gods, the Pitṛs,
> to Men and to the Fires).
>
> ‘Bad books’—e.g., those written by Cārvākas and Nirgranthas; those
> that are not trustworthy, and have no connection with Vedic rites or
> their effects.
>
> ‘Histrionic art’—acting, dancing and singing.—(65)

Further explanatory notes by Ganganath Jha are as follows:

> This verse is quoted in Smṛtitattva (p. 538);—and in Prāyaścittaviveka
> (p. 192), which has the following notes—‘anāhitāgnitā’, omitting to
> kindle the fires by Śrauta or Smārta rites, when one has the capacity
> to lay them,—‘steyam,’ appropriating of articles other than gold,
> slaves, horses, silver, land and deposits,—‘ṛṇānām anapakriyā,’ the
> non-payment of debts due to Gods, Ṛsis (Ṛṣis) and
> Piṭṛs,—‘asacchāstrādhigamanam,’ the study of heterodox
> literature.—‘Kauśīlavasya krīyā,’ constant addiction to dancing,
> singing and music.

Now since promoting sex,alcohol etc. are heterodoxical to Hindu scriptures this verse can be seen as loosely applying to the question.

Comment: Means,  watching films promoting alcohol is sin. So, what sources of entertainment are justified by scripture. I want to know.

Comment: Singing, dancing etc. are allowed but I believe too much addiction is considered as bad like in this verse:  7.47. Hunting, gambling, sleeping by day, censoriousness, (excess with) women, drunkenness, (an inordinate
love for) dancing, singing, and music, and useless travel are the tenfold set (of vices) springing from love of
pleasure. @Hope

Comment: Excessive addiction leads to downfall and it should be avoided.

Comment: @Rickross can you create a chatroom for us to discuss dharmashastras?

Comment: @Haridasa https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151438/dharmashastras

Comment: @Rickross I am in it and will type my first message ping me then.