# Is capital punishment allowed in hinduism for abuse?

Tags: krishna, punishment

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shishupala)-

> In the Mahabharata, Shishupala's mother was given a vow by Krishna,
>   her nephew, that he would pardon his cousin Shishupala for a hundred
>   offenses. When Yudhishthira underwent the Rajasuya Yajna, he sent
>   Bhima to obtain the fealty of Shishupala, now king after his father's
>   death. Shishupala accepted Yudhishthira's supremacy with no protest,
>   and was invited to the final ceremony at Indraprastha.
>
> At that event, the Pandavas decided that Krishna would be their
>   honored guest. At that time Shishupala insulted Krishna as a cowherd
>   and worthless to be honoured as a king.[2] At the same event, he
>   committed his 100th sin and was pardoned by Krishna. On insulting him
>   again, which was considered as the 101st sin, Krishna released his
>   Sudarshana Chakra on him and killed him on the spot.

Comment: I guess it is difficult to format the question well? ;-)

Comment: I like how pretty you made it - but I don't know how to do it @Rohit

Comment: Read relevant information from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: and see edit history to know how I formatted.

Comment: How is that abuse? He forgave him 100 times!

Comment: you're making it sound like capital punishment was dealt solely for abuse. there is history behind sishupala in previous janmas.. these are avatara rahasyas.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do scriptures say about using swear or abusive words for cursing people?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15460/what-do-scriptures-say-about-using-swear-or-abusive-words-for-cursing-people)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to the question in the title is **NO**.

There are punishments given for verbal abuses in the Manu Smriti but those are not death penalty.

The punishments are based on the Varnas of the persons involved.

In most of the cases the penalty is just a fine as sanctioned by the king of the state. The only case where the punishment is severe is where a Sudra abuses a Brahmin or a Kshatriya. If a Sudra abuses a Vaishya then also the penalty is just a fine. So, death penalties, as punishments for abuse, are not sanctioned/mentioned in the scriptures.

See the following verses:

> Manu Smriti 8.270. A once-born man (a Sudra), who insults a twice-born man with gross invective, shall have his tongue cut out; for he is of low
>   origin
>
> Manu Smriti 8.276. (For mutual abuse) by a Brahmana and a Kshatriya a fine must be imposed by a discerning (king), on the Brahmana the lowest amercement,
>   but on the Kshatriya the middlemost.
>
> Manu Smriti 8.277. A Vaisya and a Sudra must be punished exactly in the same manner according to their respective castes, but the tongue (of the
>   Sudra) shall not be cut out; that is the decision.

The case of Shishupala was however entirely different. He was a Kshatriya just like was Sri Krishna. And Sri Krishna killing Shishupala was not a punishment for abuse because such punishments are not sanctioned and moreover Sri Krishna was not the king of that state where that incident was occurring.

Comment: why exaxtly was sisupala murdered @rickross ?

Comment: Oh that's a long story.. Didn't u read the wiki u quoted? @SK

Comment: "The answer to the question in the title is NO".  Is there any question in the body? Just an article from wiki. :D