# Views of Hinduism on self pleasure?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

What does the Holy book say (if there's any mention) about Masturbation, is it considered a sin? Please provide a source if possible.

Comment: Preserving semen is necessary, especially for a brahmachari. One cannot waste his semen unnecessarily. The only place to split semen is in your wife's body. Even if semen is accidently splitted, some atonement are there.

Comment: You can check [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/697/what-does-hinduism-say-about-masturbation) question and the answers given.

Comment: Do you only want from Bhagavad Gita or all the scriptures? The answer is already given from Hinduism Point of view.