# Do scriptures classify nightfall as sin?

Tags: sin, sleep

Ejaculation during sleep happens without explicit masturbation.

According to Hinduism, [masturbation is a sin](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14932).

But does Hinduism classify **[ejaculation during sleep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nocturnal_emission)** as a sin?

Comment: Ejacuation happens when u think about pornographies in dream and thinking about such is sin As brahmachari people don't think about such and so they don't ejacutate during dream

Comment: That thing doesn't apply to everyone. @Pravin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Atonement measures are prescribed only for actions which are considered as sins.

And, for nightfall the [Manu Smriti](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc199657.html) does recommend one such measure.

> स्वप्ने सिक्त्वा ब्रह्मचारी द्विजः शुक्रमकामतः ।
>   स्नात्वाऽर्कमर्चयित्वा त्रिः पुनर्मामित्यृचं जपेत् ॥ १८१ ॥
>
> svapne siktvā brahmacārī dvijaḥ śukramakāmataḥ |
>   snātvā'rkamarcayitvā triḥ punarmāmityṛcaṃ japet || 181 ||
>
> The twice-born religious student, haying unintentionally dropped his
>   manhood during a dream, should thrice recite the three vedic verses
>   beginning with “punarmām,” after having bathed and worshipped the
>   sun.—(181)

So, it seems to be a sin of a very small magnitude.

Samvarta Smriti however says only bathing is enough to remove that sin.

> A Brahmacharin,. who knowingly discharges his seminal fluid, should
>   perform the expiation consequent on the breach of the vow ; **and if
>   unwillingly, he should be purified by bathing.**
>
> (Verse 28 of the first Chapter)

If you see it from another angle, then nightfall can be a result of a disease and diseases don't affect a sinless person. So, although it's unintentional still it's a sin.

Medhatithi's commentary on the Manu Smriti verse from the linked page is as follows:

> When one renounces his vow of continence intentionally, then he has to
>   perform the expiatory rite prescribed for the ‘Avakīrṇī’ (11.120 et.
>   seq.); the present verse lays down what one should do when he does it
>   unintentionally.
>
> No significance attaches to the mention of ‘dream’; the absence of
>   intention is the only necessary condition; and no intention can be
>   present during dreams. Hence this same expiatory rite is to be
>   performed in a case where, even though he may be not asleep, the flow
>   occurs involuntarily, in the same manner as certain other fluids flow
>   out of the body.
>
> The sense of the verse thus is that—‘if one drops his manhood
>   unintentionally, he should perform this expiatory rite that he should
>   recite the three verses, etc., etc.—(181)

So, the first point is that the verse and the injunction is applicable only to students (those who are residing in the Brahmacharya Asrama) and the second point is if it was not a sin for them no expiation would have been necessary.

But expiation has been laid down.

Comment: Very good answer..but no intentioin can be present in dream doesn't make any sense..as if people think of pornography eveeytime it's most likely to have a dream of the same.So intention is included in dream.

Comment: Even  we can commit some sin in dreams .. that's what I have read .. This is all logical if we see from Karma .. why that particular dream came to a certain person and not to others? So, that persons previous Karmas led to that dream @PravinRGMishra

Answer (score 2):

No, Nightfall is not considered as sin in Hinduism.

[Srimad Bhagavatam](http://bhagavata.org/canto11/chapter17.html)

> 17:25 Someone of the vow of celibacy should never spill his semen and,
>   when it flowed of its own in sleep, take a bath, control his breath
>   and chant the Gâyatrî

[Ramkrishna Paramhans](http://celibacylife.blogspot.com/2013/02/quotes-by-sri-ramakrishna-paramahansa.html)

> The loss of reproductive elements dissipates a person’s strength. **But
>   there is no harm in nocturnal emission. That reproductive element is
>   from food. After nocturnal emission, a man retains enough to succeed.
>   But he must not lose it voluntarily.** What remains after nocturnal
>   emission is very refined. The Lahas stored pots of molasses with
>   holes in the bottom. After a year it was found that the molasses had
>   turned into crystals, like sugar candy. Whatever liquid there was had
>   come out through the holes.
>
> It is very harmful for a spiritual aspirant to discharge vital
>   elements. He has to be very careful not to even look at a woman (man
>   for female aspirants). Even if she is a devotee, he must leave that
>   place. Even to see the picture of a woman might cause the discharge of
>   vital elements in a dream, if not in his waking hours.

Comment: "when it flowed of its own in sleep, take a bath, control his breath and chant the Gayatri" - this means it's considered a sin and the prāyaścitta (atonement) is to take bath and chant a mantra. The second blockquote is irrelevant; it's not talking about sin at all. It's discussing whether nocturnal emission is useful for spiritual progress or not. See [this link](http://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/gospel/volume_1/20_rules.htm) for full context.

Comment: @sv. This is wrong. When the scripture prescribes some action like the bath and recitation of gayatri after some improper action, it does not imply the action was sinful, because there are other, material reasons for prescribing that action, like internal purification. For example, after you get your hands dirty, people say to wash them for cleanliness and not as a prayaschitta. It is analogous to this.