# Nightfall and Janeau

Tags: karma, lust

Will I have to change my Janeau after a nightfall?
I'm a teenager and you know almost every teen masturbates, I masturbated too but I have controlled it after my upanayanam. It's been 27 days.
Whoever controlled his Kam vasna, will he be successful in life if he he'll work hard? Having a control on your sexual desires is contradictory to success? Or should I continue not to masturbate or should I countinue it?

Comment: The following posts might be useful for you --(https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/697/4732) and (https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/34995/4732)