# How should brahmcharya be interpreted nowadays according to the vedas?

Tags: vedas, brahmacharya

According to the vedas a man who is from the age till 25 should be a brahmachari. The preservation or semen or ''virya'', will then transform into ojas, nourishing the brain and he will reap numerous benefits. Now, in the modern world how should youngsters from 12 to 25 use this principal? Many engage at least once a week in masturbation. Sadhguru said that a men should not be in denial, nor glorify the act of masturbation (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nLkJwAyx_k8). Are teenagers, according to the vedas, not allowed to release semen, or is there any kind of concrete guidance for them, like when they can or cant indulge into it?. If so, where can I read this vedic guidance? Many have heard about brahmacharya, but are we supposed to abstain from it till we are 25, should there be a balance, or should we do it just a few times a year, like every month and keep it as little as possible (what do the vedas say on this)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well there is nothing like this prohibited in the vedas

Comment: "The semen that remains after nocturnal discharge is very 'refined'. The Lahas kept jars of molasses in their house. Every jar had a hole in it. After a year they found that the molasses had crystallized like sugar candy. The unnecessary watery part had leaked out through the hole.                                     Gosple of ramakrishna chapter 20

Comment: Is this verse ok

Comment: "Now, in the modern world how should youngsters from 12 to 25 use this principle?" - this looks opinion-based to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does Hinduism say about masturbation?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/697/what-does-hinduism-say-about-masturbation)