# Adharniya Vega and Brahmacharya

Tags: belief, life, brahmacharya, charaka-samhita, living

According to Charaka Samhita(Lesson 1- Chapter 7)

[image: excerpt]

Sorry about not being able to paste in text format but as you see,

1. While Brahmcharya prohibits all sexual desires, Charaka Samhita seems to promoting this to stay healthy.
2. The remedies mentioned are strictly against Brahmcharya and even Hinduism (Madira and Chicken).

How and why is that different books depicts different way of life while following Hinduism?

Comment: First, the 'samhita' you quote is not veda. The vedas teach brahmacharya. See https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/697/what-does-hinduism-say-about-masturbation

Comment: How is this against Hinduism? Can you share a shloka from any scripture where it says anything like that?