# I am brahmin ( not following brahmachari) but does Sandhyavandane, etc!

Tags: scripture, vedas, brahmins, sandhyavandanam

I am brahmin ( not following brahmachari) but does Sandhyavandane, etc!

Can I masturbate? Will that make me impure?
Should I change my janeu later?
Please answer!

Comment: Agnipurana states that masturbation causes ritual defilement of the body, however it is minor sin which can be easily cleansed by sprinkling Ganga water on one's own self or by observing Ekadashi. Changing of the upavita isn't required. If you regularly observe sandhyavandana thrice a day, you needn't to be bothered much, because daily recital of Gayatri during sandhyavandana automatically cleanses your body & mind of sins committed daily. However you should refrain from asking personal advice over here.

Comment: See the answers posted under this Q -- https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/697/4732

Comment: 'Can I masturbate?' - technically, yes. 'Will that make me impure?' - also, yes.
it is hard to control lust, especially between age 16 and 30. it is very hard to fight it once the thought has entered your head. the best method is to prevent such thoughts from entering. the easiest way to avoid them is to avoid watching lustful pictures, and to avoid eating lustful food - meat, alcohol, onion, garlic, eggs, mushroom, drumstick.